# When is an MCTR not an MCTR? (a.k.a. change the URL of the help/mcve page)

Tags: feature-request, help-center

OK, this has annoyed me every time I've needed to link to [/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on SO, and I've just got annoyed enough to post this request:

> Please change the URL of the ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help center page on SO from "**/help/mcve**" to either "**/help/mctr**" or "**/help/minimal-example**".

(Obviously, the current URL should continue to redirect to the new one.)

---

OK, for those of you going "huh?", here's a quick background summary.  Back in January, [Shog9 asked the community for help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214955/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta) in creating our own version of [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/).  [This was done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214955/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta/215383#215383), and the [initial public version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/215383/4) was titled "How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example" — or MCVE for short.

However, [less than a week later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/215383/6), the title of the page was changed to "How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example", with the new acronym MCTR.  Alas, the URL of the help center page was never updated, so now, whenever we link to the page, we need to remember not just the new title of the page, but also the old title that was only ever used for a handful of days.

The current title has now been stable for 2.5 months, so I think it's reasonable to assume that it won't change any time soon.  Let's fix the URL to match it.

---

Ps. It would be even nicer if we also had a comment shorthand like `[mctr]` that would automatically expand to "[Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" with the correct URL, but [that's something for a separate request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217103/add-a-magic-link-to-point-to-the-minimal-working-example-help-page).

Comment: Speaking for myself, I'd find `/help/minimal-example` a *lot* easier to remember than an obscure acronym.

Comment: @TRiG: I'd slightly prefer it too, if only to avoid having to repeat this if the title is ever changed again, but I'd be OK with either. I just don't want to have to remember *two* obscure acronyms for the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, URL changes are not an option.

Changing the title to *match* the URL is though. That title had gotten a bit long anyway. The point of using an initialism in the URL was to make it easy to remember and quick to type - so changing the title was really sorta stupid in hindsight.

Note that you can now use `[mcve]` in comments, and it will get expanded to the correct link.

Comment: Well, I guess that's one way to resolve the inconsistency... O_o

Comment: Ain't there a *Magic Link interface*, where admins enter `[magic/link] => URL`?

Comment: Hmm... Not *as such*, but...

Comment: Thanks for making it consistent.  Is it OK to ask for a capital E on the 'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example', to match the letters in the acronym?

Comment: Feel free to up-vote my feature request that asks for a magic shortcut linking to that page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217103/add-a-magic-link-to-point-to-the-minimal-working-example-help-page