# Min-Reprex: a less awkward name for MCVE

Tags: discussion, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example, terminology

> **Update:** ok, ok, this was a wee bit premature - here's the follow-up proposal:
>
> [MCVExit redux: I don't need a milkshake to know when I've missed the mark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark)

---

[Five years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta), we set out to write up some guidelines for folks asking debugging questions on Stack Overflow. Andrew Thompson, author of the much-loved guide to writing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), gave us [a solid start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/215383/1); with a few tweaks and updates over the years this guide continues to provide one of the most-viewed and most-effective bits of guidance for askers.

Fast-forward to today: we have a brand-new [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live). And one of the most popular requests for improvement is... [Encourage folks to create an MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live/381695#381695). This surprised no one, as it'd [already come up several times in testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing/) - so the team recently sat down to figure out how to better integrate this venerable guidance.

...And we immediately ran into an unfortunately familiar problem:

### MCVE is an awkward name.

The full title is long, and the initialism is... Also long. [I regretted it almost immediately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258871/when-is-an-mctr-not-an-mctr-a-k-a-change-the-url-of-the-help-mcve-page), but couldn't change it. Heck, I had to add a little blurb at the bottom [just to help folks find it when searching for "MVCE"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313675/help-center-search-for-mcve-does-not-return-the-mcve-help-page). Turns out it's hard to have a discussion when folks keep forgetting the name of the thing they're talking about...

So [our intrepid new Product Manager Meg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157789/megan-risdal) sat down and tried to figure out something that'd convey the same message more elegantly... And one word quickly jumped out at her:

[image: reproduce appears three times in the introduction to the article...]

### Minimal, Reproducible Example (or, "reprex")

Yep. The common factor for both Complete and Verifiable is the need to provide a way for others to *reproduce the problem*. So... We *could* just call this thing a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example. Even better than a clunky acronym, it has a meaningful and elegant portmanteau, "reprex", which was originally coined by members of the R community, some of whom have been maintaining [a similar FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) here for many years. We were especially inspired by [Jenny Bryan's `reprex` library for R](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/learn-reprex.html) and her "help me help you" philosophy behind encouraging question-askers to create reproducible examples that make conversations about code more productive and efficient.

After mulling it over for a while, I couldn't think of a good reason not to change this other than my own inability to consistently spell "reproducible". A big part of the philosophy of the article has always been "short and clear" - so why not make the title itself shorter, and the URL less awkward? Provided we didn't break the thousands of existing links in the process, that is.

So Jon Chan has set up a redirect to allow both /help/mcve *and* /help/reprex to take folks to the same place, the same old article with a new shorter title. While updating the title, I've taken the opportunity to also work in a few other suggestions from the team:

- "you will get better answers" -> "people will be better able to provide help"

  Let's face it, there's no guarantee you'll get a good answer no matter how good your question is - you're just increasing the odds.
- "tabs make a mess on Stack Overflow" -> "tabs might not get correctly formatted"

  The subtle danger here has always been that tabs *seem* to work on Stack Overflow... Just like they probably *seem* to work in your favorite editor. Until they don't, and your co-workers murder you with a classic can of diet soda. Again, precision is important here: the danger isn't that tabs will always break, it's that they won't always work.
- Removed the now-redundant "make sure it's complete" section

  The final guidance in the Verifiable->Reproducible section was already *very* close to this; with a few more tweaks it can entirely supplant it.
- "'It doesn't work' is not a problem statement" -> "isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. There are lots of ways you can better describe your problem so it's reproducible."

  Here I got preachy instead of trying to help folks understand the reason for the advice. Meg suggested a more descriptive explanation.

And a few other minor tweaks here and there. All in all, a solid set of improvements, I think... But decide for yourself: [/help/reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). And then let me know what you think...

---

*Unfeaturing this after a day - got plenty to chew on, and hopefully most folks interested have seen it by now. Big thanks to everyone who responded - lotsa good ideas and fair critiques, will think about this for a bit and discuss more later.*

Comment: I like the name. Much easier to remember, and to remember what it stands for. "Does the C stand for complete, or compilable? Or were there two Cs?" Reprex also has nice mouthfeel.

Comment: [mcve] still works in comments *on Stack Overflow*, @double-beep. We'll try & add [reprex] later.

Comment: Can you perhaps give some comment suggestions for using the "reprex" term?

Comment: I'm probably the worst person alive to give advice on writing comments, @Travis - my usual approach is: 1) describe what's lacking 2) link to resources for adding those things. If you want to add other stuff, go nuts - but those two are essential, IMHO.

Comment: On the one hand, "reprex" doesn't emphasize "minimal", "complete", and "verifiable" the way the MCVE expansion does. On the other hand, lots of people still don't really get it when shown the full name and have to be told to follow the link, so it may not be as much of an issue.

Comment: @Shog9 It's always amazing what _whiskey_ can do with open minds and intelligence ;-)

Comment: It sounds like something that should be followed by a lot of fine print listing possible side effects.

Comment: @TravisJ "Questions about debugging must include a reprex"

Comment: I see how its a bit less wordy, but "min reprex" sounds even more awkward to my ears than MCVE. Though, I've never been a fan of portmanteau's. Fine either way  though, really.

Comment: I find the "min-reprex" name more awkward than the initialism, but most of the other stuff here sounds good.

Comment: It's a meh for me

Comment: MCVE is already a stand-in in most cases for "no repro" which has the added benefit already carries meaning outside SO... I don't see how a rebranding, reprex, makes it clearer than, for example, min-repro or even just repro.

Comment: "min-reprex" just isn't doing it for me. Remember you're typing it, not saying it. How it sounds doesn't really matter and `[mcve]` is two characters shorter than `[reprex]`.

Comment: @cs95 `reprex` might be two characters longer, but it's probably *significantly easier* for those unfamiliar with SO to unpack it into "reproducible example" than `mcve`, which is more valuable than terseness.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perhaps... I hope you're right :)

Comment: To me, it sounds like something you should be embarrassed about when you ask your pharmacist for it. "Less awkward" is not a phrase I would use to describe it.

Comment: Avoid sun exposure while using Reprex™

Comment: Oops. I thought from the title of this post that it was a joke - how could "min-reprex" possibly be *less* awkward than something else? I like the thinking, but maybe keep iterating? (One issue for me is that it's not obvious how you even pronounce "reprex". Is it "re-prex", or "rep-rex" or "reep-rex"?)

Comment: MCVE is awkward, but at least it has the redeeming feature of clearly being an abbreviation for something.  "Min-Reprex"?  My first reaction was "Did I accidentally stumble into 'Stack Overflow in Latin' or something?"

Comment: One thing I don't like in both is the word "example". That makes sense in the context of bug reports ("here's an example of some code that produces the error"), but less so in the context of Q&A, which should generally be "here's my actual code, as close as I can pinpoint where something is going wrong". It's not really an "example" of anything.

Comment: Yeah, because “reprex” just *rolls* off the tongue so much better than MCVE. You’re a month and a half late here. I don’t even know how to pronounce “reprex”. At least I know how to pronounce the letters M, C, V, and E.

Comment: My first thought was it was something about memory repression. Why not just "Minimal reproducible example"?

Comment: I like that too, @tiny. But, Reprex is already used for this purpose in some quarters, while MRE is... Mostly used for brown plastic wrapped meals.

Comment: Is this all really just about the page's URL? I mean ok... not sure anyone will really notice it. IMM what's important is the text the ones who need this link, will read. And for this, [MCVE] magic-link is ok in its current form: it logically unfolds to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which makes it easy to make a sentence with, that even if the user doesn't visit the page they will still understand what we want, and this for only 6 chars. Not sure that setting the focus on this brand-name was the wisest move...

Comment: Min-reprex just does not state what it is about. MCVE tells the user that they do not understand the word so they look up the meaning, and get a clear, four word explanation of what is required and expected from them

Comment: reprex what is that???? Misspelled regex...

Comment: The _min-_ prepend makes it really awkward (more than MCVE imo), as demonstrated by about half comments (and your suggested shortcode) skipping it. Imo going full copycat and just naming it reprex would be way better.

Comment: This solution is worse than before. But maybe just say "MCV-example" instead of "MCVE" would already be a small step forward (slightly longer, but one letter less to parse.

Comment: Is reprex even a word? I couldn't understand Min-Reprex without a glossary, while Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example is kind of self explanatory, even if a bit long. How about something more ambiguous but also more understandable like fully fledged example or fully specified example? Or just leave MCVE, it's a word conveying a lot of information in 4 letters.

Comment: I like it how you introduced a change the community dislikes, aimed at helping the community, without having consulted the community at all. At least it fits the usual workflow. I know, I know, just because an annoying and loud minority on meta disagrees doesn't mean anything and so on. How about managing Jobs instead? (I don't use that.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak - and apparently not even all the moderators like it!

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I would expect that the more veteran a user is the less they are going to like it. It's only expected, the site hasn't been very welcoming for old users for a while :P

Comment: Surely others said it already: "reprex" is much more confusing than MCVE. It sounds like some kind of regex. IMO this change is a mistake.

Comment: I am mainly against this because you have not asked, and just introduced the change. This is not the ethos that SO used to have, changes were community driven.

Comment: I don't care about reprex, but now that redirects are apparently an option, why is `/help/mvce` still not a thing (along with `[mvce]` of course?) Whatever the arguments for or against reprex (and whether it stays or goes), I see a lot less for the case against `mvce`.

Comment: MCVE is already the most common used term for this. Changing it to other term is not going to help, only confuse more people. So lets just continue using MCVE or just stop using a made up term and use a description like "minimal complete example" or "complete example".

Comment: Title suggestion: Min-Reprex: a **more** awkward name for MCVE

Comment: This looks like a micro-optimization to me. And while it requires a lot of effort to implement (re-educating users to use the new term, changing the help pages), it looks rather unwarranted. You want to change the well-estabilished term because... the old one sounds a bit awkward to *your* taste?

Comment: I'd propose to call it a "Code Unit Neatly Testable" instead. Oh. Wait. Maybe not.

Comment: In all seriousness: Changing from "MCVE" to "MRE", with "RE" standing for a portmanteau that **needs explaining** doesn't seem to make sense for me. Whichever acronym or portmanteau is used, it should *be* a link to the respective page anyhow. (And the implications of renaming that page, in terms of link rot, are *so* significant that I don't consider it worthwhile...)

Comment: I salute the attempt to reform and improve something which has such existing currency and inertia.

Comment: Good luck changing anything these days, the conservatism is linear with the age of the community.

Comment: @Alex There's a lot of energy behind changing MCVE, but making it longer and more abstract is not the way to go.

Comment: @Alex there are [plenty of things the community wants to change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes&pageSize=50). The problem is what they _will_ change is either something we never asked for, or otherwise carried out in a way that makes things worse. It's not like the community is a miser with suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a minimal regex.

Comment: "I can't reproduce your problem. Please provide a minimal regex, so we can trouble-shoot both problems."  :)

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)!  Short, Self-Contained, Complete Example.  I also note that 1st April was a month and a half ago, or is still more than ten months in the future (or both).

Comment: A serious question, @Shog9: If this proposal had come from the *community* would you have been in support of it? It's astonishing to me that the first *mention* of this idea on meta is a post that presents it as a *fait accompli*.

Comment: I want to make sure that it is clear: **This isn't the normal "Meta Negativity" from the regulars rejecting a new change that [gets ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348)**: the people who most frequent Meta and were seeing the post first tended to upvote it ([26-4 in the first few hours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/384994/timeline#voteaggregate_636934751999999999)). These downvotes may represent many nonregular users brought in by the featured tag, and shouldn't be dismissed.

Comment: The MSO irregulars like me don't need to come here very often — unless there is some tremendously silly suggestion being made, @DavyM.  I really don't think this is a good idea.  I really dislike this change-for-the-sake-of-change suggestion.

Comment: That [Irony...](https://imgur.com/a/RMqilUJ)

Comment: I would much rather type [mre] and have it expand to a linkified "minimal reproducible example" than type [reprex] and have it expand to what? "min-reprex"? The expansion still requires expansion.

Comment: MiniRepro is more pronounceable than min-reprex.  It's also more nearly self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm going to continue to call it `mcve`, because it is already etched into our community and it simply makes a lot more sense (imo). I frankly find it ridiculous that a change like this would be rolled out without any discussion, and then we are expected to just go with it and completely change our established behavior _for no reason whatsoever_. This entire thing leaves a _very_ sour taste in my mouth, and the feelings I have toward the way SO has been managed lately are indescribable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I always remember MiniLuv, MiniPax, MiniPlenty and MiniTrue, so MiniRepro is that one I'm bound to forget?

Comment: Reprex sounds like some sort of birth control drug. Or a new and strange version of a regex. I disagree with the change proposal and support keeping MCVE

Comment: I also hate the acronym "IIFE" for "Immediately invoked function expression" in Javascript.  But "Ultra Scope" sounds too much like powerful mouthwash.

Comment: I think you should realize by now how unpopular and terrible this idea was. Can you share with the community why you took it upon yourself to make these changes without consulting with the community first? And why you're ignoring the backlash here?

Comment: @mason No matter how much outcry there is about this, all of the feedback given by the community will be ignored, and the change will stay in effect. This has become extremely common here it seems.

Comment: At least with MCVE every letter stood for something. Why does reproducible get 4 letters? The equally horrid `repex` is one letter shorter. Or maybe just go with a Dinosaur, the `M-REx`

Comment: "Heck, I had to add a little blurb at the bottom just to help folks find it when searching for "MVCE"." This could have been a hint. Making it "Miami Vice" compatible for eased remembering.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yeah I figured that. But we shouldn't stop trying to hold them accountable. Maybe I'm just an unrealistic idealist...

Comment: @mason Oh yeah, I totally agree with you there.

Comment: Why is this featured? Somebody's decision or a poor algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to be an improvement.

Comment: I'm just trying to be open about the changes, @alec - I'll un-feature come evening.

Comment: No, yeah, this being featured is a must. If something like this happens over our heads the least one can do is keep us transparently informed.

Comment: I like "MiniRepro" as suggested by Jonathan Leffler. It sounds less awkward than surprise reprex.

Comment: @Shog9 Right idea, bike-shedding aside. As for the language it expands to, why not A/B test it, so brand-new users get a vote? By the time they've found meta SO, the specific wording is probably not relevant anymore.

Comment: @TravisJ `[repro]` is probably what we'd *really* want to type.

Comment: @jpaugh [agree]

Comment: Literally thought this was a joke.

Comment: maybe we can do better than mcve, but reprex is certainly not it

Comment: Reprex sounds like something I'd need antibiotics to get rid of.

Comment: Forgive me, but I must be missing something...how is `/help/reprex` shorter than `/help/mcve`?

Comment: After we have discoverd the T-Rex (Tyrannosaurus Rex) we have now the RepRex (Reproducaurus Rex)

Comment: You do know you can say MCVE/MVCE in two syllables right? "MV CE" - "muh-v c" or "MC VE" - "mc v". Probably would sound whack the first couple of times, but I'm sure Min-Reprex would anyway, so there's really no downside.

Comment: @Shog9 What community response would be needed for you to revert this change? Or is there no response that would achieve that goal? I tried to ask another question but the loud and active minority that like your reprex idea voted it down and closed it.

Comment: "Reprex" sounds like some sort of (sports) energy drink.

Comment: It's got *electrolytes*, @Script47...

Comment: @Shog9 why are you ignoring direct questions asked of you and just making jokes instead? Do you understand  how bad that looks?

Comment: See my edit, @mason. I've responded to every question I have an answer for at present; the rest I need to think about.

Comment: maybe tag this status-review?

Comment: you got me to make an account on meta. sigh. reprex is *not* less awkward than mcve, please revert this. Literally making an account just to write this.

Comment: In the upvoted answers there are 2-3 quite good proposals that should definitely be discussed and maybe implemented further. It kind of also shows that some matters require a feel for the community and can be better solved by asking the community than by asking any engineer to solve on his/her own. No offence intented. Other things surely are better decided by StackExchange staff decisions. The question is how to proceed from here?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ebkj9x5Ko

Comment: May not have been mentioned before, but we may also have "**testcase**" as another possible synonym.

Comment: @Cœur I don't think that's a very good option. It comes across as something that's needed for "_my code misses some edge cases_" debugging problems, but not "_my code blows up_" or "_it doesn't compile_" or "_I have a clear problem but I forgot to show my actual code_". Sounds too much focused on input, at least to me.

Comment: I'm one of many formerly very active meta users who aren't very active anymore. One thing all of us have in common is that the company appears to care more about coming up with hairbrained things to tweak or implement instead of actually acting on highly upvoted feature requests. What's the point of the tag?

Comment: This is a joke/troll, right?

Comment: I originally read "min-reprex" as "min-regex." I wondered what the new regex was.

Comment: Reads like newspeak.

Comment: [Google for mcve](https://www.google.com/search?q=mcve): About 2,190,000 results, top result is relevant.  [Google for sscce](https://www.google.com/search?q=sscce): About 149,000 results, top result is relevant.  [Google for reprex](https://www.google.com/search?q=reprex): About 67,900 results, top result is unrelated: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex.  This change seems inadvisable.

Comment: Thanks for pushing this change through our throats, given the -267 feedback from the community, as well as most answers going against it as well.

Comment: So, what happens next?  Seems to be a consensus that this change was inadvisable, but https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve still redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex which contains the text, *MCVE was also the former name of the page you're reading now before it was renamed to Minimal, Reproducible Example (or “reprex”).*  Must I now start telling new questioners to include "reprexes" in their questions, and deal with the "reprex/regex" confusion?

Comment: @dbc: Continue to use MCVE — you'll have to manage the URL manually since it appears that typing `[mcve]` no longer yields anything useful ([mcve]).  I'm taking it as an opportunity to use `[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)`, thereby removing the unnecessary `and` and capitalizing `Example` too — things which irked me about the previous version but not enough to make a fuss about (unlike this change!).  I have a tiny shell script that generates the information that can be copied and pasted to the relevant context (on a Mac, I use `mcve | pbcopy`).

Comment: @Will: I think it's a case of "idle hands do the devil's work" — they've got too many people on staff so they have to think of things to do, rather than doing only the critical things.

Comment: That magic link never worked on meta, @JonathanLeffler. It still works unchanged on main.

Comment: The next step is taking the suggestions here to the dev team and seeing what can be done, @dbc.

Comment: Can we please have it reverted "while" the dev team ponders over the suggestions, in an endavour to do things in the correct order of business really? The longer this "sits", the more this is an insult to the feedback provided here honestly, and creates more confusion for Search engines and the people linking to mcve. If not, one of the less mouthful suggestions such as MRE might be more palpable perhaps, but reprex is tougher to use and explain than MCVE, it is not more intuitive. Please revert the change atleast until a decision with some more consensus is reached.

Comment: If this was easy to change I'd have done it five years ago and we wouldn't be discussing it now, @ParitoshSingh. But it isn't. So I'd rather change it as few times as possible. Machavity and Cœur have the right idea, IMHO - make the URL meaningful and leave short names for redirects / magic links... If we can get that done, then only one more change is needed.

Comment: I can understand that. At the same time I just also want to emphasize this sitting in its current state is also not a good vibe/sign though. But alright, fair enough. I hope we can get things moving on this issue soon, as long as the current state does not become the de facto standard by just being "slid under the table". The quick response placates me for now though.

Comment: @Shog9 — OK; my bad.  Yes, using the `[mcve]` notation on SO works (but not on MSO).  I still counsel using MCVE — if only because it has the benefit of recognizability.  Frankly, until you raised the controversy, I don't think it was controversial, either — it was generally recognized as an SO-specific term.  That people don't know how to use it in a comment is a secondary problem; the term itself is fine.

Comment: A little late to the party, but a guess as to why people are using MVCE (at least why I did), I think of it as a Minimum Verifiable Code Example

Comment: Wow, congrats! (as of now) 305 downvotes!

Comment: I'm genuinely curious why Stack felt the need to go ahead with this change, despite this question being at +59/-363 currently. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Well, technically we kinda went in an orthogonal direction, @jhpratt: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark

Comment: The problem with this damn site is that after unambiguously being told NO, we don't want to change **MCVE** to **MRE** (Meals Ready to Eat) - you did it anyway. Now you have to put an entire **Complete** section in the MRE page because without it, MRE results in nothing but incomplete snippets being posted.  ***If it ain't broke -- don't fix it!***.

Answer (score 289):

## You haven't defended your claim

> MCVE is an awkward name. The full title is long, and the initialism is... Also long.

No, it isn't. MCVE is incredibly short. The full title isn't short, but it's hardly a burdensome length.

> Heck, I had to add a little blurb at the bottom just to help folks find it when searching for "MVCE". Turns out it's hard to have a discussion when folks keep forgetting the name of the thing they're talking about...

1. Your only real complaint is that people mix up the C and the V. Fine. I can agree that getting it straight is a mild annoyance. But if that's the problem you're trying to solve, **just say so**. Don't make up stuff about "MCVE" itself being too long or "awkward."
2. Even when people mix up the C and the V, that doesn't mean there is any real problem with communication. You haven't demonstrated any actual problem communicating about MCVEs.
3. Why did you have to add that note? Google brings up the MCVE page immediately when searching for "mvce":

   [image: SO's MCVE page is the first result for "mvce"]

My point is that you have failed to articulate the problem you're trying to solve. Instead, you're presenting the "solution" you've already arrived at, without delving into the problem and considering other possibilities.

## There's a simpler option you didn't consider

The far simpler thing to do would be to popularize **both** MCVE and MVCE as valid representations of the concept. There's no reason why the C and the V have to be in that order anyway. Dealing with this common typo directly would be far easier than trying to popularize a new name and insisting everyone change a good name they've been using for years. If you can make `help/mcve` and `help/min-reprex` work at the same time, you can do this for `help/mvce`. Add a note to the page that it's also sometimes abbreviated "MVCE," and you're done with minimal disruption.

## This change reduces the clarity of the term

I object to dropping the "complete" and "verifiable" terms. These terms are there to combat *specific* categories of errors when creating an example:

- Complete: The code example should be complete is that it is fully functional. Another user should not have to add missing variables, functions, classes, etc. to make it work. They also shouldn't have to make guesses or assumptions about the environment the code is being run in; all dependencies and any specific environment conditions should be articulated. This is a common problem when users post questions.
- Verifiable: The example should reliably reproduce the problem. Another user should be able to see the incorrect output immediately after they've executed the code. It should do exactly what the author says it does when they run it. It should not throw other errors that are not the subject of the question.
- Minimal (for completeness): It should not be a code dump of 2000 lines. It should be a short, easily read block with as little logic and as few dependencies as possible. This reduces the number of possibilities other readers need to check to identify the problem.

Dropping these two words makes it *more difficult* to communicate the common problems that led to the creation of the term "MCVE." Having them separated out makes it easier for someone reading about the concept to understand its purpose and intentions. This is vastly better than "Minimal, Reproducible Example," which doesn't articulate these common errors as clearly.

## You don't seem to have understood the term

It is worrying to me that you did not come to the realization that each word bore particular significance yourselves. It shows me that you didn't examine why each term was included originally. You did not take the time to understand the intentions of the people who developed the original name and understand what it was trying to communicate. Instead, you railroaded it into what *you* thought was important. This is a common trend among modern SO employees, and it undermines my trust in the organization. Doing that goes against SO's core values, both in terms of how to treat other people and in terms of improving your own understanding of a problem.

If you had approached Meta about this change before implementing it, any number of users could have explained this. By implementing it before coming to this understanding, you have again demonstrated that you do not value your established community's thoughts on these matters.

Comment: I know good and well why each *section of the page* is there; I've been editing it for five years now. And for five years, I've been regretting stuffing those section initials into the URL, because all too often folks throw around the initials instead of the relevant section name(s). I was aiming for a short little path name in the help center, but now I see "MCVE" popping up as far afield as Reddit without any context or link back... But until today, I couldn't change the URL without breaking thousands of outstanding links, so I had to just live with what carelessness wrought.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*I object to dropping the "complete" and "verifiable" terms.*" They haven't been dropped. They're simply not part of the short form anymore. And it's not like they were part of MCVE if you didn't already know what it stood for. The fact that "reprex" is a term in usage among at least some subset of programmers for this *exact* same concept is enough to make it legitimate to substitute our made-up word for theirs.

Comment: @Shog9 "because all too often folks throw around the initials instead of the relevant section name(s)" Why is it the responsibility of a close voter to explain every last detail of what's wrong with a question someone has posted? It isn't. It's the author's responsibility to go read the page and figure out what's wrong. The whole point of having the page is so that users *don't* have to explain in detail to every question asker.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*MCVE is incredibly short.*" In text. In spoken language, its 4 syllables. "Reprex" is two. "*It's the author's responsibility to go read the page and figure out what's wrong.*" He's talking about off-site, where there's no convenient mechanism to create a link back.

Comment: @Shog9 "...but now I see 'MCVE' popping up as far afield as Reddit without any context or link back..." Do you think people can't Google the term? Clearly, it's a widely known term. Why is that a problem at all? How is this even relevant?

Comment: I don't care if close voters skip explaining their votes altogether, @jpmc26; if a close vote needs an explanation, we've screwed up the close vote to begin with. There's a close reason that *links directly to this page* already - if you have to post a comment with *another* link, then we have bigger problems than the term used in the URL.

Comment: @Shog9 "But until today, I couldn't change the URL without breaking thousands of outstanding links, so I had to just live with what carelessness wrought." It's not carelessness to choose your terms carefully. The fact you even think that the name is reflective of carelessness just proves my point.

Comment: @Shog9: The reason people make those comments is because the OP won't know to edit their post until it gets closed for that reason, at which point it's more-or-less too late. Indeed, I've seen people delay providing a close vote for precisely this reason: so that the OP can have time to fix their question before it gets closed.

Comment: @Shog9 "if you have to post a comment with another link, then we have bigger problems than the term used in the URL." Yes, and that problem is that most askers do not have any interest in crafting a high quality question. Changing this to "reprex" won't help with a user who isn't interested in improving their question anyway.

Comment: That goes back to what I told Travis earlier today, @Nicol: the crucial part of such a comment is explaining what's missing. [mcve] is a handy way to quickly link to a handy guide for more info (and isn't going away), but the term alone explains nothing.

Comment: @jpmc26: You seem unaware that "MCVE" is a term invented by SE, for that page. And Shog himself says that it was not chosen "carefully" at all. So... what exactly is your point here? SE created a term that has become popular, but they don't like that term and are replacing it with something that has a history of usage outside of SE. What's the problem?

Comment: Nor will doing anything else, @jpmc26 - the less effort expended on such askers the better. I wasted far too many years honing the mechanics of and writing guidance for question-bans, with little to show for it; going forward, I'd rather be building guidance for folks who *will* read it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Actually, yes, I am aware of it's origin here on SO. It *was* chosen carefully, and that's evidence by the fact it was a *revision* of SSCCE. You don't revise an existing term to increase clarity out of "carelessness."

Comment: @Shog9 Then how is people posting comments that don't point out the specific word from the term relevant or even a problem? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with this discussion.

Comment: @jpmc26: You realize that Shog is the person who *invented the term MCVE*, yes? You cannot argue that a term was invented carelessly or not with the person who invented it. By definition, they know more about its invention than you do.

Comment: I literally just took the initials of the first four words in [Andrew's first draft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/215383/1) and shoved 'em in the URL, @jpmc26. I didn't give a moment's thought to how that decision might play out over the years, I just wanted a URL to link to and took the easy road. I was far more concerned with the content of the page at that point, and when I regretted it a few days later it was already too late.

Comment: @NicolBolas Shog just posted a comment showing he didn't develop the term, so that's wrong.

Comment: @Shog9 The fact you initially "regretted" it doesn't mean anything. You still haven't demonstrated that it's actually causing any problems. The author who *did* develop the term clearly thought it through very carefully.

Comment: @jpmc26: The comment says that the initialism (aka: the term in question) was taken from the first four words of a draft. That doesn't sound like any care was taken in developing that initialism. But if you wish to take that as some confirmation that you're right, I can't stop you.

Comment: By the way, I covered the entire history of this page, with citations, in the announcement above. Most of it's in the *first paragraph*. I'm not sure how much I want to bother reiterating here.

Comment: @Shog9 You didn't cover how the updated version will still communicate the same concept and accomplish the same purpose. The original term acts as a mnemonic, reminding the reader of the three the problems the term was designed to address, as I spelled out in my answer. The new term does not do so. Addressing that would not be repetition in any form.

Comment: I'm highly skeptical that it reminds the *reader* of anything, @jpmc26. It's an easy to remember URL for *writers*, and it certainly helped *me* remember the fairly unwieldy title over the years... But I'm just as happy to forget that and finally learn to spell "reproducible". Fingers always try to cram an 'a' in there for some reason.

Comment: @Shog9 "But I'm just as happy to forget that and finally learn to spell 'reproducible'." This is exactly the problem I'm talking about. You don't care about the fact both the term and the abbreviation target specific problems with posts, and that makes it easier to understand and remember what the term exists for. The new term fails to do so.

Comment: @Shog9 "By the way, I covered the entire history of this page, with citations, in the announcement above. Most of it's in the first paragraph. I'm not sure how much I want to bother reiterating here." Perhaps you should have written an MCVE. :)

Comment: @jpmc26 - minor comment on your third point: 'Why did you have to add that note? Google brings up the MCVE page immediately when searching for "mvce"'. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point, but I think Google is returning that page precisely _because_ of the note; you can see in the summary result, Google has emphasized the "mvce", which I believe is there precisely to achieve that objective, no?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Thanks for pointing this out. I'm going to look into it, although I'm having trouble figuring out how. I can't exactly reproduce the Google searches from before it was added. It looks like the mention is gone now, though, so maybe we can find out in a couple days.

Comment: @Shog9 FWIW, the term "Min-reprex" doesn't explain anything either; I thought it was a mathematical term until I read your post. Not only is it longer than MCVE, but reprex isn't a word... it's parts of two words arbitrarily smashed together. "Min-repro" (for one example) would be shorter than "Min-reprex", and better than both "Min-reprex" and "MCVE" in that you can guess what it means without having to google it. It also has the added benefit of being a common abbreviation for reproducible and is already used here in the phrase "no repro".

Comment: @TylerH "Reprex" is equally clear as "regex" is. Regex is pretty much accepted now. We're at the start of the movement, so reprex isn't, but there is nothing inherently different from regex. Both are expression made from arbitrarily mashing two words together for ease of use.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The difference is that regex is well-established already, and doesn't have any competing shorthands. "Min-reprex" (not even just "reprex") is a *new* attempt at changing an existing shorthand, so it has different barriers to entry. It's also a bit of an apples to oranges comparison; regex is an amalgamation for an algorithmic approach to pattern matching across various programming languages, reprex/min-reprex is a less elegant amalgamation of a *subject matter-agnostic* approach to getting assistance.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier For me, a change from MCVE to anything else has to be at least: A) not longer, and B) not more confusing/abstracted to be considered worthwhile. Min-reprex or even just reprex fails *both* of those absolute minimum criteria, let alone whether you think it might be a better term (I don't).

Comment: This answer needs more hand-drawn red circles.

Answer (score 199):

## Min-reprex will further confuse non-English users

We already <s>deal with</s> welcome broken English as it is. Let's not break it more intentionally.

## We already have an ecosystem for MCVE

In addition to the page, we have the `[mcve]` shortcut for comments (`[minreprex]` seems like a step backwards) and the closure reason

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

## If we're going to simplify, just go with Reproducible Example

Yes, Minimal is important (walls of code suck). So is Complete and Verifiable. But Complete is implied by Reproducible, as is Verified. I think you're right that **reproducible** is probably the key word here, but "reprex" doesn't *communicate* that. People have to understand reprex first and *then* make it reproducible. So let's just communicate that up front. Here's how I would write the closure reason

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **a minimal example to reproduce the problem**. Questions without a clear problem statement, and/or a way to reproduce the problem, are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Reproducible Example //stackoverflow.com/help/reproducible

No more reprex, MCVE or anything like that. Help us reproduce your problem. 99% of the time that's what I have to explain at work (IT, coding, life in general, etc. needs reproducibility).

Comment: I support using the term "help us reproduce your problem" 100%. By all means, just say that.

Comment: "*[minreprex]*" I thought the intent for the shorthand was to be just `[reprex]`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any reason for a long short link. When we get around to updating comment magic links we'll just expand both [mcve] and [reprex] to the title of the page.

Comment: NB I would suggest **minimal example to reproduce the problem** -> **minimal example that reproduces the problem**.

Comment: *and* [mvce] for those who cannot remember the order

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, and Reprex *still* confuses me. I've read the entire post, know that it's just the same MCVE as always, but when I read it, I don't recognize it as anything; not an acronym which does stand for something else, and not a word which stands for itself. I've read a bunch of comments and my first reaction is to read it as "Reflux" misspelled rather than giving it any meaning.

Comment: `s/deal with/are forced to/` in the first sentence.

Comment: @DavyM That's because "Reprex" isn't a word in English.

Comment: Nobody found "regex" to be intuitive at the start, and look where it is now. Reprex is a similarly efficient word. Don't get me wrong, I'm not so confused by mcve anymore (I even get the letters in the right order most of the time) but Min Reprex is totally fine for me.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I definitely wasn't around back then but I'd assume people knew what "regular expression" is and that's definitely a cumbersome term to keep throwing around, so it seems natural that it'd eventually get shortened. And "regex" is not very ambiguous when in context. However, this change is trying to do *the opposite* - starting with the shortened term "reprex" to popularize the longer one. If you were told yesterday to provide "reprex" would you honestly instinctively think it's a "reproducible example"? I'd imagine you'd google it and discover...a library. Not very clear.

Comment: @VLAZ "reprex" is not very ambiguous either when in context. "reproducible example" would eventually be reduced to "reprex" through usage. Minimal Complete **Reproducible Example** is already in our language. **Reproducible Example** is already in our day to day language. Shortening it to reprex is not the stretch people are trying to make is seem like. As for the google argument, "regex" would assuredly not have returned correct results at the start either, it was not popularized.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier so yesterday that would have been completely clear to you? EDIT: and I'd argue that it *is* ambiguous because it exists and it means something different.

Comment: Yes, it was. There's no reason it shouldn't be, presented in context.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "you need to provide a reprex" doesn't sound like somebody misspelled regex or maybe meant some weird regex dialect to you? *How*? Because THAT is the context you would get - anything more and you'd be explaining what the term *is*. Honestly, if somebody told me "give me reprex" I can see this also meaning "give me <some medicine>" which would be weird but I'd assume it's a play on "chill pill" or something. If I google it and find it's some library I'd be even more confused.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Wait, are you implying there's some part of regex that was intuitive at some point?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "*Minimal Complete **Reproducible Example** is already in our language. **Reproducible Example** is already in our day to day language*" I'd like to come back and address this, too - really? It's **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **e**xample. I can't think of many (any?) times I've seen somebody use "reproducible example" on SO. I can't say it hasn't happened - it seems like something that can come up but it's far from regular. Definitely not *daily* - doesn't come up often outside SO. You yourself *haven't used it* within the last two years. Hardly "common".

Comment: @VLAZ heh, indeed. I misremembered it. So much for MCVE being clear at all. Imagine that, I've been aware of, and using regularly, the term for *years*, and still the letters get mixed up? How is that better than reprex?

Comment: @Machavity Yes, I do imply that regex is quite intuitively used widely in the programming world, is it not? Unless you mean that, people would not stumble on it by themselves?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier again, the "regex" usage rose up organically, it wasn't forced. And you wouldn't get confusing information if you google "regex". Moreover, pretty much any programming language calls the construct some variation of "regex", so even before coming to SO or some other context you are likely to encounter that term. Not so with "reprex" - you'd only find it on SO or if you're within the R community. There is hardly a valid comparison between the two.

Comment: @VLAZ Googling "regex" when it was just starting to be used would not have turned up any result, no, as it was not widely used yet. The idea that a term should have only one meaning is irrelevant, there's way too many things in the world, and the internet for that to be a valid endeavour.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "*The idea that a term should have only one meaning is irrelevant*" it's relevant if it is imposed as a new term with a different meaning. It will be confusing for people not familiar with the term (incorrect meaning would be found) and probably for people familiar with the other term (it's not the same thing). So it's relevant there. Remember, this is an attempt to create the term and push it onto people, it's different if it rises up organically.

Comment: @VLAZ Are you aware that at the present moment, googling reprex turns up exactly the definition of "reproducible example"? What problem are you talking about? [This is the result for googling reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/). ***It's literally already pointing towards Reproducible Example***. You are really pushing it with the "trying to impose" anything, the term already exists, it's a plea to start using it.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I get a link to a GitHub page. Thus I go "oh, it's a library". The next hit is the link you gave me...which has the same name as the GitHub repo, thus my logical conclusion isn't "Ah, a *completely different* and *unrelated* thing" but "must be the library's main page". The other hits talk about a reprex package, thus it still seems as if it's not about the term. Even if you look at that page it gives you information on how to use the reprex library to make stuff for R. So, it sounds to me like somebody is saying "give me a jQuery in Python" - nonsensical outside R.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - You may be unaware, but Google results are different for everyone, based on region, usage, etc

Comment: @Richard I am er, very much aware, actually. Interestingly, you do not seem to want to tell that to the other folks in the discussion that base arguments on google results?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - It may interest you to learn that my top result for reprex is this; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html. It does admittedly give you a definition of the word, but it's not a generally intelligible document.

Comment: Google is not a top result only service. I do hope that your usage of Google goes farther than blocking on the top result when trying to understand something @Richard. FWIW, it was mine as well. Then the second (!) was a very clear citation of Reproducible Example. A human with a brain able to lace their shoes should be able to read all the way up to the second result of a google search.

Comment: The point is that arguing "Reprex is not google findable" is misdirecting at best, and downright made in bad fait at worse. Reprex is totally learnable with google. In this case, the context being very clearly Stack Exchange, it's really strange how people seem to insist that it's non findable that reprex means Reproducible Example.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - Any shortcut that I then have to scrabble around to find the meaning of (let alone find out what it means in practice) isn't a shortcut. It's a longcut.

Comment: Reading two google results excerpts is not a longcut @Richard. It's literally one sentence away. Like two or three centimeters down on a screen. One doesn't even have to actually click the link, the sentence is right there.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier none of the excerpts make it clear what the term is. The entire first page of results for me looks like either a software library or [completely](https://vandercookpress.info/vanderblog/reprex/) [irrelevant](https://annuaire.plan.nc/import-export/import-export-produits-divers/reprex) [links](http://www.briarpress.org/41538) [that](http://www.degustajaen.com/establecimientos/reprex-distribuciones/) [that](https://glitch.com/~wild-hardboard) make me think "give me reprex" is at least a typo.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I haven't seen anyone say it's not google findable, most of the complaints I see are saying that it can be confusing to users trying to find a definition, and I agree. Almost every hit on Google leads to a package called [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/#reprex-pkg). Yes, it does say "_the first step is to create a reprex, or reproducible example_" however, there are 10 more pages of results, and most of them do not give this description. How would a clueless user proceed? They should click through multiple websites? Googling MCVE takes you straight to the MCVE page

Comment: yes @GrumpyCrouton, because years of usage have made Google react correctly to it. This argument is completely shallow, given use and time, googling for it will be exactly the same. You folks are comparing the result of years of google searches with the day 0 google search. Most of all pages about MCVE are **not** about the SO one either, so please have some coherence about how you reflect on this. If you take into account all the pages for reprex, *do it for mcve as well*, and take into accounts more than the first few results about it.

Comment: I mean, over the first 10 results, five of the ones I see now are for results completely unrelated to the SO mcve. Your argument is completely incoherent @GrumpyCrouton. A clueless user would not have an easier time with mcve than with reprex. And if we go over the next pages, as you so gladly do it for reprex, ***literally nothing is about the right mcve***.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Not really, because what you just said helps my argument. MCVE has been used for _years_, it's well-established. Are we changing MCVE just for the sake of changing it? I'm not one to "fix" things that aren't broken, and why should the community be _forced_ into this change that such a huge part of the community disagree's with? IMO there are much bigger fish to fry instead of wasting time with nonsense like this which effectively does nothing to better the community but in fact makes it worse by trying to change something already so deep in the community.

Comment: Now that is a completely different argument @GrumpyCrouton, which I can agree with to a degree, but it is infuriating to read arguments about google results when people willingly do not apply the reflection to both searches, or willingly do not take into account the historical use of mcve influencing the results. If we're to consider ten pages of results, let's do it for both terms, or not at all, but not only when it supports one's opinion.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I never explicity claimed anything about the 2nd page for either, I hadn't looked. But I think you should take another look at the google results for `mcve`. On the 1st page, 7/10 can take you to the correct definition. On the 2nd page 4/10 can, I don't see any on the 3rd page. For reprex this is a lot harder to measure, because I can't tell from the links if it's for the reprex package, or a page explaining what a reprex is.

Answer (score 164):

In addition to everyone else's objections -- all of which I agree with -- if you google "reprex" you get a bunch of stuff about a specific R package and its Python analogue.  This will almost certainly be diabolically confusing for anyone who comes to Stack Exchange with questions touching on data science or machine learning.

If they're asked for a 'reprex' they'll likely google the unheard-of term, see that it's a package, install the package and start going through the documentation to see how it's related, and so on.

Comment: This is IMO an even better argument against "Min-reprex" than the fact that the term is just extermely awkward. Repurposing a word which already has a ton of google hits to very specific things in the context of programming (R package, python package, R documentation, Rstudio FAQ, ...) is simply a bad idea. It will either make search results worse for SO users unfamiliar with the term, or if the SO pages eventually outrank the current results, for everybody who currently uses the term.

Comment: To me, this argument alone is enough to drop the "reprex" term altogether. Creating confusion when we ask an user for a "reprex" is about as far as we can get from the purpose of asking for said "reprex".

Answer (score 111):

"Min-Reprex" is awkward.

TemporalWolf's comment had a clearer name suggestion: "Min-Repro".

Simply visualize the title of this Meta question being:

> *Min-Repro: a less awkward name for MCVE*

And now you can clearly understand it's not about regex or another brand of vacuum cleaner.

Well, we're dealing with neologisms anyway, so it's the usage frequency of any of those formulations that will decide the outcome. Not that *reprex* is bad, maybe it's acceptable, but it could have been worth having an open poll before renaming the page.

And for most people to understand it, maybe we could have the URL being a full title:

> /help/minimal-reproducible-example

and everything else (mcve, reprex, ...) being redirects to such clear title. This is a common practice for instance on Wikipedia where they define [shortcuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:SHORT) for frequent URLs.

Comment: +1, but "reprex" definitely is bad.

Comment: "*it's the usage frequency of any of those formulations that will decide the outcome*" The usage frequency of "repro" is precisely zero, while the usage frequency of "reprex" is higher than that. Do a Google search on it, and you'll find a small group of programmers who settled on this term for this concept.

Comment: If you want to call it a "Min-Repro" or a "MRE" or even better a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" go right ahead. I'm perfectly happy to see folks use the *title of the page* instead of the abbreviation, since [we shouldn't need a page just to explain a help topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean). The value of Reprex over both MCVE and Repro is that it is both sufficiently unique *and* has seen enough use outside of SO to actually stand a chance of meaning something to new askers... Who, after all, are the folks it is intended to be used by.

Comment: I don't hate that idea. But I also like short paths. I nearly always type help center URLs from memory.

Comment: @Shog9 You [just said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385004#comment696466_385004) that MCVE is widely used outside of SO. What evidence do you have that users aren't encountering it elsewhere? I have never encountered the term "reprex" before. I doubt it's any more widely known than MCVE.

Comment: I actually suspect you're right, @jpmc - I've been shocked by just how common the term has become. But that's a problem: it's jargon for the folks who most need to know what it means. The last change I made to the page prior to today was adding information on runnable snippets... The utility of the page lies in getting folks to provide a demonstration of their problem, not teaching them a new word for "code".

Comment: @Shog9 ...And "reprex" is not jargon? Wat. If you're going to use jargon, at least "MCVE" has the benefit of emphasizing its intentions and connotations. MCVE becoming a common term is not a problem in any way, shape, or form. All this change does is add even more jargon that's harder to understand.

Comment: I did briefly consider PCMCIA, but...

Comment: Not sure about this suggestion. "reprex" sounds like some weird mutation of "regex" to me. While "repro" seems like you've misspelled "repo". If I didn't see this meta post and I was asked "can you give a repro", I'd assume they are asking me to set up a GitHub repo with the code or something.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry, I don't buy that. Not only is it especially not appealing to me to go with a confusing neologism "because a *small group of programmers*" 'once decided on that, but when I decided to bite on your Google challenge, I found the exact opposite of your claim: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repro%2Creprex&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crepro%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brepro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRepro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BREPRO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CReprex%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @NicolBolas And if you meant just purely google search, I found 38,400 results for "reprex", and "42,300,000" results for "repro". Tell me how "reprex" is higher usage frequency, again?

Comment: How about "MiniRepro"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ...and now you're in 1984 territory.

Comment: I'd strongly support `[mre]` as a replacement: reproducible covers complete & verifiable, so Minimal Reproducible Example seems like a step in the right direction. And, my military background agrees with the Meal, Ready-to-Eat symbolism: I shouldn't need anything else to process it, except maybe a [rock or something](https://taskandpurpose.com/heres-ridiculous-story-behind-rock-something)

Comment: @NicolBolas what? "repro" has been around [longer than stack overflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anutthara/2007/12/05/your-developer-can-never-say-no-repro-to-your-bug-ever-again/) . Bugs have been being "closed-norepro" for ages. Maybe since bugs have existed...

Answer (score 105):

> And we immediate ran into an unfortunately familiar problem: MCVE is an awkward name.

Says who? This is the first time I see anyone make such a remark. Seems to me you came up with a solution for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean I got to agree that at first sight when you would look at the abbreviation, it looks a bit strange and you would require to look it up to understand its meaning, but once looked up, makes sense. Simply replacing the text with e.g. "example" with an anchor leading to the definition of **MCVE** would suffice. Even easier would be, adding a tool/button which could generate this automatically for an author of a given answer, question and/or comment. But why change things if those work just fine?

Comment: @Barrosy *"I mean I got to agree that at first sight when you would look at the abbreviation, it looks a bit strange and you would require to look it up to understand its meaning"* - and reprex doesn't?

Comment: It does not make sense at all if you compare the it to the description of MCVE and the reason for it being abbreviated. @Lankymart It does not make sense because MCVE for as far as I know worked perfectly fine and like I said, why fix something that ain't broken?

Comment: @Barrosy I know, I'm agreeing with you. :)

Answer (score 101):

The original new version contained "MVCE" along with "MCVE", which I thought was reasonable to help readers seeing the old name find it via google. Apparently [this was a mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/384997#comment696434_384997).

So you're unhappy with the old name because it's "confusing" and "awkward" and not meaningful enough, and hard to google in its own right (trivial to google with the old SEO boost of the old MCVE page). So you introduce a new name that's harder to say, has little visible meaning, contains a dash, and remove the original SEO trick so that people searching for "MVCE" won't even find it. Because this is what will happen.

[image: xkcd 927: Standards]

You dislike the current situation where people *might* (don't) get confused about what they are told, partly because people get mixed up between MCVE and MVCE (presumably, I've yet to see this). So you introduce a third and weird name. Now you will have *three* names in circulation, only two of which will lead the reader to the corresponding meta page. Success I guess.

Comment: To be fair, I think the mistake was only _after_ the edit. Before the text said "You may have been told to include an MCVE by some helpful commentary, or perhaps even an MVCE if they were rushed", but the new, post-edit text wasn't attempting to highlight the common typo. Not that it changes anything, the common typo should obviously remain in some form to keep the page near the top of Google for 'MVCE'. Hopefully removing it was simply an oversight and it will be put back in. I mean, _hopefully_ all of this will be reverted, but...

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave unless I'm misunderstanding you now, that's what I was trying to say with my first sentence. The "original new version" was the one that contained MVCE, but then Shog "fixed it" as per the comment.

Comment: You're right, but in context, in the "original new version", "MVCE" was just a typo - the sentence it was in wasn't attempting to demonstrate that the initialism is sometimes presented in the wrong order, it was just using it as a term: "MVCE was also the former name of the page you're reading now". In the "old version", it was part of sentence saying "you might see it like this". Presumably that was to clarify any confusion and for SEO. I totally agree with your point though - in some form the typo should exist in the page.

Comment: I don't like this xkcd because it gives no answers.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev what do you mean? What answers? It's not meant to give answers, other than "trying to fix 14 standards with a new one will only give you 15 standards".

Comment: @AndrasDeak And that is horrendously wrong -- that's why I dislike it. It basically implies: "The problem is unsolvable. Go kill yourself, you can't win." The worst possible advice to give. It is possible to solve it but the focus needs to be on the people who use the existing standards: whatever you suggest must be a "clear winner" for them for some reason. It's not necessary to cover all user cases, either: use case requirements may be so different that it's impossible (or at least unclear how) to cover them all and maintain ease of use.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I think of it more like a cautionary tale than a prophecy.

Comment: @AndrasDeak cautionary tales are rubbish, specifically because of that "you can't win" implication. The real answer is "you can win but you need to be careful so you don't waste time making the same mistakes as your predecessors (but there's nothing wrong with making new, yet unknown ones)". They miss the "you can win" part, and that poisons the whole aesop. I fell victim of that omission and it tooks me many years to come to it myself, and I cannot forgive the fools who preach this lie for that.

Answer (score 77):

No.

What.

Why.

*Why.*

## Why?

Of all the things that are a problem on Stack Overflow, of all the things that need fixing, of all the things that could be fixed...

You chose the one that is literally the opposite of a problem. And then you made it a problem, and invented a terrible solution for this nonexistent problem. And here we are.

Mere words cannot convey how absolutely asinine this suggestion is. It is not just bad, it is not just useless, it is an extremely bad idea. Attempting to imagine the mental gymnastics that went into justifying this, is headache-inducing.

Every time I think the disconnect between Stack Overflow and its community cannot get any wider, something like this happens. You guys need to stop, get out of your echo chamber, and actually ask what real human users want and need from the site, not hypothetical fairy users from Saturn.

Comment: I'm torn. One may agree with this, but the way this was phrased is not constructive.

Comment: better chat feature ? gold hammer option to not hammer every question with a single vote ? no let's work on the next april joke ;)

Comment: ["The best feedback I ever received had fairly dismissive tone.."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030352_314348) @E_net4

Comment: @gnat In a way, I stand corrected. Yet, I'll seek to read the opposing point of view by the fairy users from Saturn when I have the time.

Comment: Calling something pants on head [...] is probably undermining your point by quite a bit and will most likely cause people to dismiss it for lack of politeness. I edited it out, partly because I suspect that the post would otherwise be deleted or edited anyways as per the code of conduct.

Comment: Also, the rest of this answer is probably going to have an equal and opposite effect to the intended one. Imagine if someone said what you just said, but to you about something you worked hard on and are passionate about. Can you imagine a framework in which that could result in anything else then a doubling down type of reaction? I can't. So what is the reason for posting this? Just venting or actually wanting to change something, because if it's the latter this needs further work.

Comment: @Magisch, I think the tone of this answer perfectly represents the anger and contempt that much of the established community has for recent changes. The fact that nobody seems to be listening will only increase the anger and contempt. Constructive suggestions seem to be ignored, so the next step is anger. After that, people leave.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Yes, I'm aware that it is a self reinforcing negative feedback loop. Someone has to break it. This isn't helping.

Comment: @Magisch, you're right, of course. Still though, I can't blame people for feeling like this, especially when far less constructively-phrased rants on Twitter/Reddit seem to get results.

Comment: This answer cracked me up. I needed a laugh. Agree.  For the love of all things helpful, make it easier to close and delete stuff! I know they want to get better quality on the site, but in the meantime, while they're trying to make the site more user friendly, at least give people the tools to keep it clean.

Comment: I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a [change].

Comment: I agree; this really feels like a "ha ha, the community is pissed at us and feels really disconnected from the company, so much so that all is lost.... so let's have a real laugh about it on the way out by doing _something like this_" FML

Comment: @Magisch Although you're not really wrong in the general case, I find it hard to believe that somebody could "work hard on" or "be passionate about" an acronym.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't knock the amount of work and understanding that has to go into UX research and related changes. I can't judge how substantive this work was considering it's not in my area of expertise.

Comment: @Magisch Fortunately, it's in mine :D

Answer (score 60):

*(On screen we see two question marks and their dog leisurely walking over a meadow in sunshine)*

> If you have a *question*, **Reprex** may be right for you. Side effects of **Reprex** are uncommon, and include headache, nausea, vomiting, death, dizziness, various ejaculations, dysentery, cardiac arrhythmia, mild heart explosions, varicose veins, darkened stool, darkened soul, lycanthropy, trucanthropy, more vomiting, arteriosclerosis, hemorrhoids, diabeetus, virginity, mild discomfort, vampirism, gender impermanence, spontaneous dental hydroplosion, sugar high, even more vomiting, brown, your mom, and mild rash.

<sup>[Source](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SideEffectsInclude)</sup>

Seriously? "Reprex"? Is supposed to be less awkward than MCVE? You missed the date by about 6 weeks.

I would write more text, but I don't even understand the problem. `[MCVE]` unfolds into a real, almost full sentence and you can write a full English comment without ever even seeing the term MCVE. It's in place and established in the community, and it's working. You want to change its name from an obvious abbreviation, to something that sounds like it needs health insurance to cover its costs. Please don't. Just don't.

Comment: Cody Gray wrote in a comment above: "_You’re a month and a half late here_". And you wrote: "_You missed the date by about 6 weeks_". Is that a meme or is it related to April fool jokes?

Comment: It's about Aprils fools... if it had been 6 weeks ago on April 1st I would have laughed about it and thought it was a good one.

Comment: Side effects include virginity? I need some reprex!

Comment: @DavyM be careful with the dosage - you might get vomiting or your mom.

Comment: Reprex sounds like the brand name of a competitor to [Durex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durex). ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring only reprex is destined to fail as "Rep" stands for reproducible.

Answer (score 59):

There need not be any other name for MCVE. The thing about MCVE is that it is an initialism not used for *any other purposes*, so first occurrences of `mcve` in anywhere in comments, meta posts and alike could be linked to `/help/mcve` as is.  In addition to that, for those that do not remember whether it is mcve or mvce, both orderings could be accepted. Try to do that with [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reprex).

If anything, the title could have one more word added to it: **yet**, to signal the contrast between minimality on one side and completeness and verifiability on the other.

Additionally both `[mcve]` and `[mvce]` in *comments* should expand to [minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to popularize the initialism even further. And so could `[example]` - what else would they mean anyway?

Comment: Maybe example could additionally by made bold: [minimal, complete and verifiable **example** (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [List of magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000). `[mcve]` is listed there.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess they meant "both" as in ... "both", not only [mcve].

Answer (score 53):

This entire effort seems to me to be misguided. The problem isn't that MCVE is too wordy or otherwise unknown to new users. The problem is that people commenting about it aren't being specific or direct enough when they drop a boilerplate comment about needing an MCVE.

Most of the time, what this boils down to is that the problem is not sufficiently reproducible with the current amount of information in the question, or that there is *too much* code to properly reproduce the problem in isolation.

There isn't a single short hand phrase you can choose that will have the desired effect of condensing individualized and complex fact specific advice into a shorthand. So I propose we axe that endeavour right out.

Instead of calling on people to submit an MCVE, rename the article to something more descriptive and outwardly helpful like "Help us understand and reproduce your problem" or similar. Link to that only in a full sentence explaining why, not just that you need a way to reproduce problems.

People (and by extension askers) can be appealed to effectively via their self interest. The message we need to convey isn't

> You need to add an MCVE (link to the article)

Because that frames it as if it's something that the OP *does for our benefit* instead of something that the OP does because *it helps them get their solution faster (or at all)*

> We need to reproduce your problem to start working on a solution, you could work on #ProblemAreaTheQuestionIsUncleaIn or #''. Here (link to the article) is a guide to help you do that"

Soul searching for a better word seems to me like micro optimization and missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: This exactly!..

Comment: Couldn't agree more!

Comment: It seems the proposed solution here would require much more lengthy comments. Not sure, enough people have the patience for it. I think you say it nicely in the second paragraph: "The problem is not sufficiently reproducible with the current amount of information in the question, or there is too much code to properly reproduce the problem in isolation. What we need ultimately is something like a meaningful example (link to mcve)."

Comment: @Trilarion I think the lengthy comments issue can be addressed by a larger menu of prefab comments and an easy way to select them. I'd be more inclined to comment helpfully on code dumps if I could just click "Prefab Comments" > "Example" > "Code Dump" to auto-insert a comment (written by someone more patient and eloquent than I am) suggesting the OP put more effort into minimizing their example code.

Comment: Indeed, when I leave a "provide an MCVE" comment on a question, I almost always couch it in terms of "We can help you better if you ..." or "You'll get better answers if you ..." or sometimes simply "we don't have enough information to answer the question.  Please ...".  The point is exactly to convey that it is in the OP's interest to do it.

Answer (score 46):

Honestly, changing it to another in-house (or small part of the programming community) term is not the solution. It's yet another term newcomers don't understand and regular users will take time to adapt to. It needs to be simple as possible. We have so much trouble even getting people to post answers in the answer box, let alone craft a decent question. Keep it simple. (imo)

The only noun in the phrase Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example, is Example. The rest is describing how the example should be.

Provide an Example (or Sample) - then explain it need to be Minimal, Verifiable and Complete.

So the page can read something like:

> ### How to Provide an Example
>
> bla bla bla bla this is what we need to help you... whatever, more
>   blas

So comments can read:

> Read how to provide an [example].

With a hotlink to the page.

Comment: But it's not an "in-house term". As explained, the term "reprex" has some usage in the R community for exactly this concept.

Comment: How many people use R? @NicolBolas

Comment: More than the number of people who used MCVE before SO created the term.

Comment: @YvetteColomb all the pirates!

Comment: I mostly participate on other network sites, and I rarely see MCVE used. "Sample" or "example" are most common and people get it.  As for "reprex" it may be used in R community but to be fair stackoverflow isn't just about R alone; I've never heard of it in Linux community, nor in Python context, nor in C context.

Comment: @NicolBolas yet only a small fraction of the people that _now_ know what a MCVE is

Comment: @YvetteColomb You don't need to use R to be confused by a bunch of technical R topics when you put "reprex" into Google, trying to figure out what it means.  If you're not using R it means someone's likely to just assume the person made a typo or doesn't know what they're talking about by bringing up some unrelated R concept on their JavaScript question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Comparing the number of people who use reprex *now* in the R community to the number of people who *used* MCVE *before it was invented* is absurd on its face; the usage of *both* terms at the same time (e.g. before their invention) was of course **zero**. If you want to compare the number of people in the R community who use the term "reprex" now to the usage of MCVE, you have to compare it to the usage of MCVE *now*, too, not some cherry-picked time in the past.

Comment: @Nicol: I get 61k hits on Google for "reprex", and 941k for "mcve".

Comment: "Please provide an example (some link)!" Wouldn't this kind of get reactions of the sort of "But haven't I already given an example"? And then one might be stuck in iteratively explaining the M, the C and the V in "example".

Comment: @NicolBolas _"More than the number of people who used MCVE before SO created the term"_ Even if that were so, Stack Overflow has since then brought it to _literally millions and millions of people_. How many people had heard of it ten years ago is utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 42):

The question as asked looks like a textbook example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

The actual problem you are facing is

- ***"How to integrate MCVE into the Question Wizard?"***

So ask that! It's possible that the collective Meta community wisdom brainstorming will produce more useful ideas than you and your product manager could by yourselves.

You didn't really give any details on what the exact integration problem is, so I can't say anything more on that topic now.

Comment: "...the exact integration problem..." Probably right after the wizard asks "do you have a debugging question, if yes then we would definitely need a MVCE from you ASAP!!!"

Comment: [*"How to ... ?"* is not a good form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56625)

Answer (score 35):

Have you considered that you may be attacking the issue from the wrong angle?

A while ago you yourself raised a concern about posts that [should be improved but haven't been and won't be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293457/839601).

Think of these posts. Think of multiple close-worthy questions hanging open and slowly dying without any meaningful feedback, and think of how having these serves one purpose: to keep askers oblivious of what they need to improve.

Maybe people have a problem learning about MCVE not because it's hard to pronounce, but because the system doesn't let them learn that they need it.

If questions lacking an MCVE were closed with an appropriate reason and in a timely manner, askers would learn themselves what they need to do. They would learn because the system would tell them what they need in a clear and timely way.

They would learn even if you renamed it to [jIyajbe'](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/26597306/jIyajbe). Without that people just won't learn no matter how you name it - because they won't even see that they need to learn.

---

Related: [Declaring a Review strike until efficiency improvements are implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented)

Comment: well, in rust questions we get some folk that always refuse to make mcve (on question that require it ofc), we got some issues that have been posted on meta and sometime on reddit. Everytime, other people tell then they are wrong but their peoples refuse to learn.

Comment: *"Have you considered that you may be attacking the issue from the wrong angle?"* - It's a well known fact that SO usually attack an issue from the wrong angle. Just another in a long line of bad decisions, nothing new here.

Comment: Hah, I had a feeling that was Klingon before hovering over the link. Nice.

Comment: I just realized what this change reminds me of: people who advocate plain-English programming languages.  They look at existing programming languages, see all the funny symbols they use, and think that if they replace those symbols with English words, programming will become far easier.

Comment: @Stargateur You may be right, but those people who refuse to help us help them are just unhelpable and won't attempt to learn no matter what we do.

Answer (score 34):

So, I kinda jumped the gun here - this would've been a heck of a lot easier if I'd posted *before* the URL changes went out. I don't really have a good excuse there; I got sloppy. Still, y'all came through with a lot of good feedback in spite of me, and it'd be a shame to let that go to waste - so let's see if we can fix it...

After chewing on this discussion for a bit, I found two answers especially insightful:

1. [Machavity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385006#385006):

   > I think you're right that reproducible is probably the key word here, but "reprex" doesn't communicate that. People have to understand reprex first and then make it reproducible. So let's just communicate that up front.
2. [Cœur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385003#385003):

   > And for most people to understand it, maybe we could have the URL being a full title:
   >
   > ```
   > /help/minimal-reproducible-example
   > ```
   >
   > and everything else (mcve, reprex, ...) being redirects to such clear title. This is a common practice for instance on Wikipedia where they define shortcuts for frequent URLs.

This... Probably should've been obvious to me, but I was still stuck on the notion that I needed a short URL and didn't consider that it wouldn't need to be a short *canonical* URL. Especially if we had plenty of [magic shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

I did a bit of quick & dirty text analysis of comments mentioning / linking to MCVE over the past year - the other term that jumps out is simply "example" - mostly, but not entirely, because a fair number of folks don't use magic links - they type a term or title and the help page's URL.

Based on this, my recommendation going forward is:

1. Rename the [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) to `minimal-reproducible-example` - no more guessing at what it links to.
2. Create a redirect from /help/reprex AND /help/mcve to /help/minimal-reproducible-example
3. Create magic links for [reprex], [repro], [mre] and maybe [example] that result in a link to /help/minimal-reproducible-example
4. Alter the *existing* [mcve] magic link to link directly to /help/minimal-reproducible-example

This should leave folks with a host of convenient, easy-to-remember ways of linking to the page, while making the page URL itself as descriptive as the title and getting rid of the *need* for invented terms altogether.

Comment: Thank you for taking a step back to take the time to listen to and consider the input here. What you've detailed in this answer is a *much* better way to handle the issues that precipitated this change and those issues described by people here in response to the announcement. This should allow both the continued use of MCVE and the progressive adoption of wording that might be more intuitively understandable to those who have not previously encountered that acronym.

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is for users to create good questions, which can be answered. Clearly communicating what is needed from the OP in order for that to be possible, in a way that is understandable to them, is very important. If changing the wording that's generally used from "minimal, complete, verifiable example" to "minimal, reproducible example" helps communicate what's needed in order to be able to answer a question, then our making that change is a very good thing. As these things tend to develop, I expect MRE is much more likely to see wide adoption than other non-"MCVE" suggestions.

Comment: Given that one of the ongoing issues with MCVE was that a significant amount of the time people use MVCE instead of MCVE, it seems like it would be a good idea to also have /help/mvce be a redirect to /help/minimal-reproducible-example, and have `[mvce]` as a comment shortcut. While this is commonly a typo, and is likely to see declining usage, it's a low-effort change that will make people's lives easier, from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for owning up Shog9. Great to see that Meta feedback isn't always discarded as "grumpy opd Meta's". I fully support this way forward.

Comment: You might going to hate me for this but I suggest you re-add the misspelling of MCVE and the new shorthand terms in the help page as well, for searchabiity. So please bring back "MVCE" and add "mre" and "repro". I noticed that searching for "example" does put the correct help page on top of the result so that is all good.

Comment: I support this way forward as well, much more than previous dicussion. Thanks Shog!

Comment: I've stuffed as many terms into that footer as I could think of, @rene. Why the hell not...

Answer (score 33):

I feel like a lot of the frustration from this change is that it is being delivered to us in the fashion of: "Hey, I already did this thing."

Whereas most of the steps in the history of the MCVE solicited community involvement, or were initiated by community suggestions.

Essentially, what's happened is that something that was community-driven has had control reverted to one employee, and the community is being told that their involvement is no longer relevant.

I personally have no cards in the specific matter of MCVE v Reprex, but I find that the model being used to make this change has become part of a frustrating pattern for SO/SE. This alone makes me bristle against the change. I prefer to cast my votes *before* the changes, instead of after.

Comment: Unfortunately "_the community is being told that their involvement is no longer relevant_" isn't exactly breaking news. There have been very clear signals for a few years.

Comment: SE tried that with the [New Contributor icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/193762).  Feedback was almost universally against it (even with the positive votes).  It happened anyway.  I'm wondering what good talking to your community does if there doesn't seem to be any listening going on.

Comment: @fbueckert they are talking _to_ us, not _with_ us. They are informing us of the change. Otherwise someone would have to ask where the MCVE link has gone.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yup.  Communication broke down quite some time ago, and this continues to reinforce that the community isn't welcome to participate in changes.

Comment: @fbueckert as long as "_people on meta are a bunch of toxic evil people who are an annoying minority_" is a legimate view within the company it's unsurprising if they don't ask that toxic bunch for advice (instead they can just look for feedback on twitter)

Comment: @AndrasDeak While I agree, I don't think having this conversation in the comments of an answer is all that constructive.  If you want to take it to chat, I'm available.

Comment: Then add on Welcoming and Stack Overflow TV (wow)

Answer (score 30):

The only problem I've encountered with MCVE is people using the initialism without linking to anything. Since it doesn't mean anything as is, anyone not familiar with it would need to go and search for it.

Using `[mcve]` expands it to the full name and adds a link, thus avoids this problem.

If we were to use "reprex" (regexp? repex? reprox? Is that a dinosaur representative?), this would have the same problem: "reprex" also wouldn't mean all that much as is to most. How many people instantly knew what it meant based on the title of this question? Certainly not me. And that's *with* the context of seeing the familiar MCVE right next to it.

Based on how awkward it is to say (see also: the comments), it doesn't seem particularly elegant either.

I could get behind using "reproducible", as this is a common term in programming, but I'd rather just have it be MCRE then. Or MRE, but you did keep "complete" in a bunch of places on that page, including the main headings, so clearly the "C" has some value.

Comment: Making the magic comment links much more prominent and well-know would have helped way more than how much harm I expect this change will do.

Comment: @AndrasDeak making magic links more prominent is going to be very useful. I didn't even know about the `[mcve]` magic link until I saw this post. I was only vaguely aware of the tag magic links and only because I posted a meta question for some tags and a helpful person edited all my direct links to the tags to magic links. Heck, I didn't even know they are called "magic links". After I saw the post this morning I finally had the knowledge of their existence and the vocabulary to [look them up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links)

Comment: @VLAZ FYI, you can click on "help" when editing a comment to get to [a list of all (or most of) the magic links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) (although they're actually only called "shorthand links" there), and I would recommend any regular user read through that and the other help center pages at some point. I wouldn't know how to make it more visible without giving it more visibility than would make sense (given all the other important stuff), except maybe by displaying the help by default with the option to hide it (as a global option).

Comment: Maybe MCVE and MVCE in comments should automaticaly be changed to [mcve] to always have a link.

Comment: Imagining Rep Rex, a dinosaur representative, made me laugh at work. Thanks for the awkward moment.

Answer (score 18):

I feel this overlooks the advantage MCVE has in non-regular user recollection.
Acronyms are frequently taught as learning aides in schools, take PEMDAS/BODMAS, SOH CAH TOA, among others. It's easier to learn the acronym and from there recall the words behind the acronym. Leading to an increase in users following the rules.

As I'm a non-regular to SO, I forget the acronym and remember it as "MVC???". From here I can then expand it and get "Minimal, Verifiable, Complete" which allows me to ask better questions, as at least I've got 3/4 things correct.

With low exposure I can only see myself remembering 'Min ReaperEx'. Which makes working back a real pain, and only tells me one thing.

---

I also don't see how having something that rolls off the tongue helps the majority of the users of the site. I've not, verbally, spoken to anyone from any SE site.

This only helps SE staff that think MVCE is awkward to say. And given that the first section of my answer doesn't affect SE staff, I can see why this would be a cute benefit internally. But I don't see why it not internal only.

Comment: That's a good point about not verbally speaking "MVCE" to anyone before.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Ironically I literally used it today in speech. Although I spelt it right ;)

Comment: It's "Min-Reputation Rex", an infamous species of dinosaur.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So that means you did not verbally speak "MVCE", but "MCVE" :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Correct!

Answer (score 12):

At the bottom of the help center page is this:

> You may have been told to include an MCVE – Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples is what they were referring to. MVCE was also the former name of the page you're reading now before it was renamed to Minimal, Reproducible Example (or “reprex”).

I think you mean this:

> You may have been told to include an MCVE – Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples is what they were referring to. M***CV***E was also the former name of the page you're reading now before it was renamed to Minimal, Reproducible Example (or “reprex”).

Comment: fixed, thanks - had that in there originally to catch typos, but now it's just weird

Comment: Don't you want to keep the common typo 'mvce' in there somewhere for precisely the reason you mention about people mistyping it?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave The misspelled mvce could be added in invisible ways that still get indexed in the crawlers, without visibly making the typo.

Comment: @DavyM - agreed, although (1) I think SEO-y stuff works more consistently if the text is visible, but I know nothing about that at all, and (2) presumably it hasn't been done, and maybe it's easier to just edit the text to include the typo.

Answer (score 11):

> Unfeaturing this after a day - got plenty to chew on, and hopefully most folks interested have seen it by now. Big thanks to everyone who responded - lotsa good ideas and fair critiques, will think about this for a bit and discuss more later.

This is asking for a blunt statement: we really don't want to discuss this matter any further. All of the necessary issues have been outlined and I don't think there is anything else to "discuss more" about. A tiny summary of all answers below:

- MCVE is already a fairly well established term, if not as a consequence of the site's own nurturing, with a higher count on search engines than most.
- Awkwardness is subjective. Even the suggested name has its own problems. Too many folks consider Min-Reprex (or just Reprex) more awkward, or just a bit too close to "regex".
- The name Reprex is also tightly related to specific packages for constructing reproducible examples, but it's not a common expression across many technologies. Searching for "reprex" is more likely to confuse people than searching for "MCVE" at this point.
- And most important, it's trying to solve an XY problem. What we really want is better guidelines and tools that help users understand what really makes an MCVE, and how to make one. In the Rust tag for example, we have gathered a list of common tips in the [tag info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info). More ideas may come from the concept of (min-)reprex in R, but it doesn't mean we have to adopt that specific name.

And meanwhile, there are so many other requested features (yet never tested, even if for a few days), totally worth trying out, that it makes no sense why this one in particular had to be prioritized and become part of the site before we even had a chance to provide any feedback.

It's high time we propose this change to be rolled back and just call it a <s>meme</s> day.

Answer (score -8):

I might be kicking the (hopefully) dead horse at this point but...

Your wonder-drug **Reprex** sounds like a Product Manager came up with it, not an Engineer or Programmer or genuine user of this site.

I knew it before I even read that far.

*(To be clear: that's a bad thing)*

Comment: You can take it to the R folks. ;)

Comment: They can use whatever they like, but hopefully we can leave R (and it's interesting terminology) to the Mathematicians and Graphics Programmers who use it and keep something clearer here for everyone else