# MCVExit redux: I don't need a milkshake to know when I've missed the mark

Tags: discussion, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example, terminology

A week ago, [I had an idea:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve) change a URL with thousands of outstanding uses and try to replace an awkward initialism with... Another awkward made-up word.

...Ok, that was... not a great idea. Fortunately, many of you generously donated your time to point out just how not-great that idea was, and some of you even suggested *better* ideas. Here's [one from Cœur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385003#385003):

> And for most people to understand it, maybe we could have the URL being a full title:
>
> ```
> /help/minimal-reproducible-example
> ```
>
> and everything else (mcve, reprex, ...) being redirects to such clear title. This is a common practice for instance on Wikipedia where they define shortcuts for frequent URLs.

That's, uh... A really good idea. It's simple, it results in a URL that consists of *actual English words*, and leaves us free to refer to it however we want.

So after a bit of discussion [last night & this morning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385296#385296), **this is what we've done:**

- The canonical URL for the help page is now /help/minimal-reproducible-example - no more guessing what it refers to.
- /help/mcve *and* /help/reprex both just redirect to /help/minimal-reproducible-example - no broken links.
- "Magic" links have been added for [reprex], [repro], [mre], [example] *and* [mcve] that all point to /help/minimal-reproducible-example - use any of those in comments and they'll be turned into a link.
- Added "mvce", "repro", "reprex", "min-reprex" and "example" to the footer of the help page itself, to aid search engines (especially our own) in finding the right page.

Still TODO: update /editing-help, look for bugs

I know this probably seems like... A thing of minor importance, a bikeshed discussion, even a waste of time. But while the naming may not be that important in the grand scheme of things, helping new askers *find* this information is paramount: the success rate for folks who read this page before asking is significantly improved over those who do not, and that translates to less frustration for them *and* for everyone who takes the time to try and help them. Anything we can do to make learning this stuff easier, less confusing and less time-consuming stands to have an outsized impact long-term.

So thanks again for all of your feedback over the past week, and for your patience. Because of that feedback, we've arrived at a solution better than any I was able to come up with on my own - it's collaborative work like this that makes me love this place.

Comment: Credit for "MCVExit" goes to [Machavity](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46265755#46265755), whose more serious feedback was also quite helpful.

Comment: -273 (ATM) is quite impressive though (he he), ;-)

Comment: I noticed this new link earlier today, when I typed `[mcve]`. I like it!

Comment: Can we please also have a magic link from `[mwe]`?

Comment: _@Shog9_ The point brought up with @Machavity's response has the nice aside irony to point at the _Brexit Chaos_ :-D

Comment: This new page focuses too much on CSS, JS, XML, HTML, etc. Perhaps you should add details for other (i.e. compiled) languages?

Comment: OK, so we're in agreement that "min-reprex" is an awkward made up word... then why do you insist on keeping it? Isn't simpler better than complex? Shouldn't there be one -- and preferably only one -- way of doing things?

Comment: @cs95 Shog has 23 score in python, odds are he doesn't live his life according to [The Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)...

Comment: @Shog Forget about _milkshakes_, whiskeba is just fine ;)

Comment: The color of the bike shed might not matter too much to you, but I just cannot stand a Reprex colored bike shed. It's worse than that awful yellow-purple ;)

Comment: +1 for the title, researching which enabled me to read hilarious reports of Brits throwing delicious banana salted caramel milkshakes at each other

Comment: this does nothing to get those that do not care enough to click on the original link and read it to click on the new one and read it either. This is just shuffling deck chairs at best ... making it where if someone posts a comment with one of those magic tags casts a close vote for that reason would actually **doing something** to get peoples attention and get them *engaged with being part of the community* instead of a *drain on the community*.

Comment: MRE is maybe [not the best choice of abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meal,_Ready-to-Eat)...

Comment: Looks like this is [causing localization issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328539/localization-of-magic-link-mcve-is-broken)...

Comment: And translation on international sites are just.. broken.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328539/141717. and we have to change our pages :(

Comment: Not sure why MRE would be such a bad metaphor, @Mark. A pre-packaged portion of code, ready for distribution with your question. Even if you don't like stretching the metaphor, TLAs are quite common, so a bit of overlap is almost unavoidable. As long as you don't overlap with something offensive or distasteful, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I should probably mention... None of the "magic" links work on meta (nor have they ever worked here) - main site only.

Comment: This is definitively better. IMHO problem of last week was more than you came with what you will do instead of coming with a problem, suggesting a solution and ask for community answers. As for the minor importance things, there's tons of post arou nd saying that naming is important and one of the hardest for us, so no it's not minor.  If some people think it's not of importance to them, they can just let those who care handle it. Finally I don't really see the problem with mvce but I don't need an demonstration that it is bad. As long the agree on a suggestion is  better then so be it.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is that one of the arguments being made is that the MCVE page is hard to find (or something like that, I really don't know what anyone saying this is talking about). Having to search for MRE would make it much, much harder than MCVE. So all that's changing is communication is being made more cumbersome (if you type out the whole thing) or less effective (if you abbreviate) than it was before.

Comment: This is a lot better than reprex. But is the highlighting of `repr` and `ex` going to be removed?

Comment: *"the success rate for folks who read this page before asking is significantly improved over those who do not"* - I am skeptical that this is because they learn anything much from the page. Rather, I suspect the phenomenon you mention here is basically 100% selection bias: carefully perusing the help center before posting is a sign of conscientiousness, and conscientious users write better posts. As such, I don't expect this to achieve much. But heck, it can't hurt. So +1 anyway.

Comment: ... and that's why I love this place. +1

Comment: Shouldn't this _Added "mvce", "repro", "reprex", "min-reprex" and "example" to the footer of the help page itself, to aid search engines (especially our own) in finding the right page._ have "mcve" instead of "mvce"?

Comment: The misspelling is important - that way folks still find it if they transpose letters, @BCharlesH

Comment: I asked you in the original post to explain why you're making these far reaching decisions without consulting the community first. You said you'd have to think about it and get back to us. Well you got back to us, but you never explained why you took a unilateral decision that affected the community without consulting the community. I am still waiting for that answer. The help center says the [community runs this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) but it seems we're getting further away from that all the time.

Comment: You removed **complete** from the naming. I think that really sucks.  It is absolutely a bigger problem than something that is not "minimal".  "minimal" is in the eye of the beholder.  "complete" is easily definable, and ascertainable.

Comment: We used to call this a "Repro" when I worked at MS Premier support. Repro being short for reproduction of the issue.

Comment: @RobertCrovella If an example in a question is not complete, it is not a reproducible example of the OP's issue, as it fails to reproduce the results obtained by the OP.

Comment: @duplode Your statement is absolutely correct. But does not address the issue, in my opinion. If everyone studied the communication carefully, and complied with the meaning, there would be no issue.  We need very simple communication that requires no thought. I view removal of the word "complete" as a step backwards.  Its OK if you disagree, obviously a great many people disagree including Shog9. And if we all worked at Microsoft, there would be no issue either. I work at NVIDIA, and we understand completely what is meant by a "full repro case" But not everybody understands terse communication

Comment: @RobertCrovella While that is a valid point, I'm not sure "complete and verifiable" is truly the no-thought alternative one might be looking for. For instance, [elsewhere in this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark?noredirect=1#comment699076_385384) Shog makes the pertinent observation that "complete" itself is potentially ambiguous.

Comment: @duplode switching to "self-contained" as a replacement for "complete" would have been perfectly fine (from my perspective) and [there is precedent for it](http://sscce.org/).  Unfortunately, that is not what happened.  Instead the concept was dropped from the terse communication.  You'll note that "minimal" doesn't appear in the precedent I cited.  That's because from a priority perspective, it's more important to communicate "self contained" than it is to communicate "minimal".

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it contains the word "short".  But just as you've indicated self-contained and complete are not the same,  "short" and minimal are not the same.  communication matters.  short is desirable, and arguably necessary.  minimal is not.

Comment: Funny story: I actually didn't know you were referring to *your* question there, @mason - I thought you were talking about Greg's. I completely overlooked your question until just now; there were a lot of comments and I was much more focused on the answers. So to answer your question then and now: this was motivated by the request to work MCVE into the new question wizard somehow, and... Kinda snowballed from there.

Comment: On an unrelated note, maybe a 301 permanent redirect would be better than a 302 "found" for purposes like SEO or something?

Comment: But without a milkshake, how will you bring the boys to the yard?

Comment: It is not the title that people do not understand. But the idea itself. Whatever you call it, you'd never get from a poor noob anything close to mcve. They will just keep posting a raw code sample, genuinely puzzled what on the Earth is wrong with it. Interestingly, the current page offers but little help. The "Reproducible" section explains anything but what does it actually mean. "Eliminate irrelevant issues" is related to M, not R. And "Describe the problem" is not related to MCVE at all. And the "Double-check" surely works. For the OP. On their PC. Contributing nothing to R as well.

Comment: Somehow I missed this discussion until now, but... this seems like a strange, confusing, and unnecessary change. Each word in "minimal, complete, and verifiable example" was important; "reproducible" doesn't sufficiently contain the idea of "complete," which is where so many examples fail. It's also confusing, in that I have literally never heard (until today) anyone call such an example "reprex," "min-reprex," or even "minimal, workable example," but I *had* heard "MCVE" many times, even before I joined SO. I realize this horse has left the barn, but I'd vote to revert this if I could.

Comment: Funny enough, MWE predates MCVE by a fair bit, @EdCottrell. Language on the 'Net is a fickle mistress.

Comment: @shog9 Fickle, indeed. I’ve just never run across that one.

Comment: The new page is great.  Why did `reprex` have to stay, though?  And why is it listed first in the list of synonyms?  That word didn't even exist until the last post suggested conjuring it into existence.  Nobody uses it, few people liked it.  Now it gets centre stage?  Why?  `This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex)` - I mean...no it's not.  Nobody calls it that. Just delete `(reprex)`.

Comment: How are the magic links supposed to work?  If I go to `stackoverflow.com/help/example`, I just get a 404.

Comment: Magic links are just terms that you can type into brackets in comments on SO that are expanded into full links when rendered, @ryan - they're convenient and can save space if you're up against the 600-char length limit.

Comment: @Shog9 Is there a list of them documented somewhere?

Comment: Yep: [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) @ryan

Comment: I think "minimal working example" is by far and large the commonly accepted name for the concept. It is the only one with its own [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), [The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Mwe) entry, and non-null [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=minimal%20working%20example,minimal%20complete%20verifiable%20example). SO has somehow adopted this "minimal complete verifiable example", but why using yet another name "minimal reproducible example"? If changing, why not fixing the schism back?

Answer (score 108):

Thank you for changing the change! It looks way better, way saner, and there's an impression of words on meta being more than just dust in the wind.

> I know this probably seems like... A thing of minor importance, a bikeshed discussion, even a waste of time.

Considering the *very* active community response to the change, I would expect that most people (and especially most people reading meta) will not think that.

Although you didn't ask for further suggestions but I'll give one anyway: I expect most of the helpful respondents to have responded anyway should you have asked *before* making any actual changes on the site. Even if (or especially if?) the question seems like bike-shedding. If you're planning to change something substantial, and you feel there's some room for the community's two cents: please try getting input from us. (We might just be able to piece together the perfect shade of fuchsia for the shed.)

Comment: Just a small footnote after rereading my answer: I wouldn't presume to educate Shog on how useful meta is. My suggestion is instead aimed at the company in general \*waves hand\*

Comment: Curiously it was Shog that wrote how not to fail on meta.

Comment: "The best color for the bike shed is fire." -- Kevin Montrose

Comment: Only a failure if you give up, @braiam

Answer (score 88):

Can we also have [mvce] as a synonym? I can never tell a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example apart from a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

I don't think we have any confusion with "Microsoft Visual C++ Express".

Comment: So much this (and also `/help/mvce` for completeness). People who can't remember the order of things, rise up and let your voice be haerd!

Comment: Yeah, I actually just came looking for this post to say the same thing after I had to edit a comment to fix my mistake.

Comment: There is a problem. In fact, the OP made a typo with this. Interestingly, we might overlook the difference easily because [our brains read jumbled words](https://www.livescience.com/18392-reading-jumbled-words.html)  just fine.

Comment: It took me ages to memorize that Minimal and Complete go together.

Comment: Should have been only [mvce] from the beginning. [mvce] somehow just looks better compared to [mcve] and you can easily remember it as "Miami ViCE".

Answer (score 25):

I'll be honest; my first reaction was "if we now have changed it 90% of the way back to MCVE, why does it still say 'reproducible' rather than 'verifiable'; why can't it just go back to the original MCVE?"

But after reading it, I really like the change in language. "Reproducible" communicates the intent of what others need more than "Verifiable", and I'm happy that "Complete" is explicit again.

So for at least this once, reason has triumphed over my dogmatic beliefs, and I see this as an improvement over what we had before.

Comment: Yes. When I asked an OP for an mcve, I often felt the need to add "... that reproduces the issue" to clarify what was needed.

Answer (score 17):

> Added "mvce", "repro", "reprex", "min-reprex" and "example" to the footer of the help page itself, to aid search engines (especially our own) in finding the right page.

I won't use "repro" or "reprex" or "min-reprex" because they still feel awkward to me for the reasons outlined by many in the answers to [Min-Reprex: a less awkward name for MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve).

It may be bike-shedding, but I suggest to wait a bit, then count how often they are used and if the use is below a threshold, get rid of them for good and replace existing ones (with [mvce] or [example]).

Comment: Are the days of reprexion over? Only time will tell indeed.

Comment: They're too close to "regex" and "repo" for my taste.  "min-reprex" feels like it should be a computer-science / discrete math term, like a minimal regex that matches what you want.  Or something about some kind of expressions.

Answer (score 15):

I'm more or less OK with the term "minimal reproducible example" being adopted as the canonical one, but if I use the magic `[mcve]` token in a comment then I darn well want the resulting link text to be "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example", just like the letters in the in the token.

I *especially* want that for all the times I have used `[mcve]` in the past, or someone else has, and I have subsequently relied upon that link text being present in an earlier comment to provide explanatory context for my later use of the simple initialism "MCVE".  Changing the link target is ok, as is the content at the new target, but changing the automatic link text retroactively is **NOT** ok.  You have changed my words, without my permission.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gets complicated in a hurry due to how magic links are rendered: there's no preprocessing here, they're replaced when the page is requested, so there's limited contextual information available and taking time to retrieve it is out of the question. Note that there are a plethora of existing links of the form, `[Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](/help/mcve)` - those remain untouched.

Comment: I don't follow, @Shog9: what contextual information would be needed?  The most basic form of my request is that "[mcve]" gets link text "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" (unconditionally), and I don't see how that needs more or different contextual information than does rendering the link text as something else.  I do know how to write the long form, but even if I had the time and energy to do it, I cannot change all my past comments, much less anyone else's.

Comment: @Shog9, I'm with John here -- in many historical comments, I refer to which of the *specific* elements of the MCVE definition ("to meet the *verifiable* element of the MCVE definition, this would need to..."); and changing the text in that comment retroactively makes that very confusing to readers. `[Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](/help/mre)` would be fine, but changing the text in addition to the link leaves things very confusing.

Comment: Ok; I'm gonna be out for the next week, but I'll try & think about this a bit - I've tossed a link to some folks on the dev team too. If anyone else feels strongly about this - like, "it's worth extra dev time" strongly - upvote & post a comment here.

Comment: @Shog9: Adding a comment here as well. I'm fine with new magic links having new link text, but it's a bit unsettling to see the words of comments I've made in the past be changed out from under me (especially since I can't edit them anymore).

Answer (score 12):

I have a minor suggestion.

Since we all agree that "reprex" is a confusing word, I suggest removing it from the top of the page. Let it stay in the footer, along with other confusing acronyms.

So I suggest changing following wording in [help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from

> When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, **repr**oducible **ex**ample, also called a “reprex”.

to

> When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: This seems reasonable; there are a few other requests here for other keywords - I think, given the proliferation of jargon, it's worth taking a sentence to explain them before moving on - how about: *This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe).*?

Comment: @Shog9 Looks good to me.

Answer (score 8):

I see this change as an improvement. On the one hand, "minimal, reproducible example" is a more straightforward (and arguably less jargony) expression than "minimal, complete and verifiable example"; on the other hand, between the [mcve] magic link and the reference to "mcve" in the first paragraph of the updated help page, people will be able to effectively use the time-honoured alternative if they so desire.

I feel it is worth addressing two specific points about the choice of words that have been raised elsewhere in this discussion.

- I don't see a change in meaning here. A reproducible example of an issue is necessarily complete (i.e. it shows the entirety of the behaviour it is meant to exemplify) and verifiable (i.e. it includes enough information for someone else to run it exactly as seen by the OP), and being complete and verifiable is sufficient for making an example of an issue reproducible. Being xomplete and verifiable is, therefore, a necessary and sufficient condition for being reproducible -- in other words, they are, for our purposes, equivalent concepts.
- "Reproducible" is not a wrong (grammatically or otherwise) choice of word. The major precedent here is the notion of reproducibility from the sciences, which translates quite straightforwardly to our context, and which can be applied to both experiments and results (I would even say that both possibilities are relevant for our purposes).

Answer (score 5):

**What happened to "Complete"?**

I have seen other point out what the letters in MCVE stand for where the question is deficient. Now I want to do the same, only to find that [my request for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261852/how-to-compile-cuda-within-clang-when-included-by-main-c-file) itself is incomplete (pun intended).

How do I ask a poster for the missing information?

Edit: The dialog box coming up on a close vote contains the following text:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must
>   include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the
>   shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.
>   Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

To me, that is a better description than the linked page provides (the one we are discussing) for the explicit references to *desired behavior* and *a clear problem statement*.
I would like it even more if it mentioned *the desired behavior* and *how actual behavior differs* from those expectations.

Comment: I believe [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385387/2751851) addresses this objection, at least in part. The gist of it seems to be that: (1) "reproducible" and "complete and verifiable" are logically equivalent, the difference between them being at most a matter of presentation; and (2) Part of the point of the revision of the changes being announced here is allowing folks to remain using "MCVE" if they feel that is more effective.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this, since it's come up a few times in comments elsewhere: the issue with complete is that there are two opposing interpretations - "complete" as "self-contained" and "complete" as "containing everything". The former is what we want; the latter is a common misinterpretation. The emphasis on "minimal" was intended to mitigate this misunderstanding, but success has been mixed - worst-case, people leave out information crucial for reproducing the problem, but include lots of irrelevant code. "Complete" remains as a section in the article itself, with copious clarification.

Comment: @Shog9 Interestingly, my own mental model of "MCVE" matches neither of those. I have taken "complete" to mean "exhibits all aspects *of the problem the question is about*". The "self-contained" part would amount to "verifiable", while the mistaken "contains everything" interpretation would be curtailed by "minimal". That, I guess, is one more anecdote in support of the point you have just made.

Comment: I the case that triggered my question a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" would have been the full source code + build commands. That would have enabled me to go and build, finding what the compiler complains about. However I would certainly not have undertaken that effort and rather just skipped the question. A "Complete Example" in my understanding would contain the error message, but I find no reference to that on the [mcve] page. The close vote dialog contains a good text in that respect, I have updated my "answer" to reference the dialog box.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot more on *that* aspect in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, tera - this is one of those situations where choice of close reason (Unclear vs OT->Debugging) makes a big difference in terms of what guidance is available, even though both try to summarize roughly what needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you, I'll cite that page in the future instead.

Answer (score 3):

I agree on a link containing only of English words.

But why didn't you use:

```
minimal-complete-verifiable-example
```

(If you want to be fancy, let all combinations redirect to it.)

Why the insistence  on "reproducible"?
Why the insistence of having it be abbreviated as "reprex"?

If you want something to spell better, why not propose "MiCoVerEx?" (MCVE and MVCE were both fine.)

It still reads awkward for me (I may get used to it) and confuses a well-defined term. MCVE has three key points about an example, now "reproducible" is used to convey both complete and verifiable and it does a poor job at that.

That leads to weird a reading that even though the "complete" is removed from the title, it's still is mentioned as a strong bullet point.

I mean this part:

> ## How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
>
> ...
>
> - Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself
> - Reproducible – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

whereas it rather should read like this:

> - Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - Reproducible
>
>   - Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself
>   - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

You are fixing something that was not broken. An improvement would have sufficed.

Comment: "MiCoVerEx" just sounds like an ex girlfriend who was either a cover-up, or a cover-girl

Comment: Isn't Micoverix a character from the Asterix comics?

Comment: "now "reproducible" is used to convey both complete and verifiable and it does a poor job at that." -> I'd say it does it better. If you hadn't read the MCVE help page, you didn't know what "verifiable" meant. "Reproducible" is very clear: it allows someone to reproduce your results.

Answer (score -18):

## You haven't demonstrated that the old name posed some kind of problem

> But while the naming may not be that important in the grand scheme of things, helping new askers find this information is paramount:

Who had trouble finding the old page? I see no reason to believe users are going to see the new page are people in increased numbers unless they  actively look for it or are guided there.

> the success rate for folks who read this page before asking is significantly improved over those who do not, and that translates to less frustration for them and for everyone who takes the time to try and help them.

Sure, that makes sense, but the only meaningful data you can have on this would be with the old page and name. So what exactly is the problem?

The only actual reason given for this change is that [you have some vague distaste for the old abbreviation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve/385296#comment696466_385004).

## MRE, the natural abbreviation, means many, many other things

MRE is the most likely abbreviation users will be drawn toward for the "Minimal, Reproducible Example." But this [has many, many meanings](https://www.abbreviations.com/MRE). If your goal is to make this page *easier* to find, this is counterproductive. Search engines are going to prioritize other exist results over SO's page for this abbreviation, and it's unlikely users are going to type out the whole thing in places where the magic link doesn't work. (Notably, when the magic link does work, it expanded to the full phrase anyway. So that's not an improvement.) So this only *decreases* accessibility of the resource.

## "Minimal Reproducible Example" is not more clear than "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"

As I noted [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385004/1394393), each word in the previous name was carefully chosen to *address a common error* in creating examples. Each word in the name and letter in the abbreviation communicated a specific quality of what makes for good example code. "Minimal Reproducible Example" drops the "complete" entirely, making it an inferior tool for communicating or remembering the three qualities.

**Leave the "Complete" in the name** to ensure that it receives as much emphasis as the other two qualities.

## "Reproducible" is the wrong word

Reproducible describes the *problem*, not the *example*. Each adjective in "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example" was carefully chosen to describe the example, *not* the problem. If you insist on a form of "reproduce" in the name, the correct adjective is **"reproducing"**.

Each word in MCVE was carefully chosen to ensure it describes the example rather than the problem as well. This is good for non-English speakers, who may have more trouble understanding it if it isn't precise.

## /help/minimal-reproducible-example is too long

This is too long. Users will typically be linking to this when they're dealing with a low quality question. As a result, they're likely to already be experiencing some frustration. Telling someone to type out such a long name will increase any aggravation they're experiencing.

---

If you're going to unilaterally ignore all the feedback to leave the original alone, then I propose the following:

## Minimal, Reproducing, Complete Example

It can be abbreviated "MRCE," which would be pronounced like "mercy." It could also be abbreviated "MiRCE," but I prefer leaving out the extra letter.

This name:

- Uses a form of "reproduce" as is your preference
- Uses the form of "reproduce" that describes the *example* rather than the *problem*
- Is as short as the old name
- Is pronounced more easily than the old name
- Preserves all three of the qualities the old name emphasized
- Lends itself well to a few puns ("Have MRCE please", "MRCE, merci")

It's at least an improvement on "Minimal, Reproducible Example." Whether it's an improvement on the original MCVE is an open question. I'm *not* a fan of changing it, but if you insist on changing it, then at least don't make it worse.

Comment: @Lino There are short links because there were short links before that they didn't want to break and so felt compelled to leave the in place. Shog's response is saying that link is the best and preferred one, though.

Comment: +1 For putting "Complete" in the title. I was happy that it's got its own bolded section again, but yeah it should be in the title.

Comment: I don't really mind the longer link. In fact, I think I prefer it - if I hover over a link and it says `/minimal-reproducible-example` I get what it's about more than `/mcve`. It's more clear what the link is about. I also enjoy "mercy". However, I feel like I'm reaching semantic saturation with all the talk about what best expresses the MCVE idea. In particular, I don't like the "reproducing" because...it's not memorable enough. It could also be "reproducible" or even further "representative" or even "repeatable". Sure, they all work but it's hard to remember what it ACTUALLY stands for.

Comment: @VLAZ The [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/216712) gets expanded to a full name. This was the case with MCVE as well. I'll emphasize that I'm *not* a fan of changing to "MRCE." I just think it's less bad than anything else they're doing and meets the minor qualities both sides are shooting for. "Reproducible" is wrong word choice, though.

Comment: I think there isn't a contest that "Minimal reproducible example" is a strict upgrade over just "mcve". No matter how many people know mcve, *everyone* who can understand english knows what a minimal reproducible example is. To the "you haven't demonstrated this is better then mcve" point, I don't think he needs to, this entire thing is bikeshedding and the new stuff is something we can all settle on without opening a whole new barrel of arguments.

Comment: @Magisch In what way is it an upgrade? I've outlined my reasons why I think that is untrue. If you disagree, then you should provide reasons why you think it is.

Comment: @jpmc26 The reasons I think this are the same that the OP post also lists. It's a complete sentence, e.g. does not require acronyms or knowing specific terms. "Minimal reproducible example" puts the focus where it needs to be, "complete" and "verifiable" are parts of reproducible and implicit in it. MCVE itself however many people know about it requires you to know the term, or guess at its resolution. "reproducing" as you suggested would also work I guess, but further changing it seems like bikeshedding (like I said above) to me. A full sentence is _fine_ and easier to read then an abbrev.

Comment: re the "too long" section: old magic links will continue to work, and will properly expand into the full url in-browser, so that is not a concern.

Comment: @Magisch The magic links already expanded to the full name before, so I really don't understand how it being a full phrase is actually a change. I am fairly certain people will just starting saying "MRE" without the link because typing it out is cumbersome (as I outlined in the answer). So again, no real change on the fronts you're talking about.

Comment: @jpmc26 It means searching for it on google you'll get a full URL, and it will be the full URL in your browser. And as I said, nothing changes from the magic links, so *Telling someone to type out such a long name will increase any aggravation they're experiencing.* is quite a red herring, as most of the time someone will be pointed to it is via a link

Comment: @Magisch Far more likely is people will have to search for "MRE," which will not as readily lead to the SO page as MCVE did. If having a full URL is so important, why not just `minimal-complete-verifiable-example`? How does renaming it help with that? I only see downsides here, most of them already covered in the answer.

Comment: "I have never seen him actually adjust his opinion on something as a result of discussion" - here's a really good recent example of it that you might not have seen: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark

Comment: _"I am fairly certain people will just starting saying "MRE" without the link because typing it out is cumbersome"_ ... You posit that `[mre]` is sufficiently more cumbersome than `mre` such that people would be more likely to type the latter? I think that's nonsense.

Comment: @TinyGiant I am talking about the contexts in which the magic link is not available, or when users simply choose not to use it. The magic link has no advantages over the old `[mcve]` magic link, which also got expanded.

Comment: @jpmc26 I see your point on "reproducible" being based on the problem, not the example, but when I read it, I think "able to reproduce (the problem)". And while that may not strictly be true in terms of grammar, I think most people understand what is meant by the abbreviation and I think "Reproducible" is more clear that "Verifiable" even though the grammar might be technically more sound in the latter case.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Did he? Let's look at the original post. The original post demands that MCVE is "awkward." It suggests changing the name to "Minimal, Reproducible Example," with enormous emphasis on using the word "reproducible." It suggests abbreviating it to "reprex." The only one of those he reconsidered was the abbreviation, which he didn't come up with a replacement for. Various forms of "reproduce" notably occur more times than "reprex" in the post. I see no evidence that he reconsidered anything about the other two.