# MCVE survives in an auto-generated text on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, hyperlinks, minimal-reproducible-example

I just noticed that the text for a question put on hold as 'no longer reproducible' (e.g. [`int` minus `unsigned long` has unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485401/int-minus-unsigned-long-has-unexpected-results) — now only visible to 10k users as it has, correctly, been deleted) still has a link to [`https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[image: image of close reasons for SO 5648-5401]

Transcription:

> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting."

The 'shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem' link uses the old `help/mcve` URL, and not to the new https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example URL. The link works; that is not in dispute.  It is simply a question of consistency.  The other close reason for the question uses the new URL in it.

Cosmetic?  Yes.  Consistency?  Undoubtedly!  (I'm infested by hobgoblins, or a little mind, or whatever else Emerson complained of.)

#### Proposed fix

The autogenerated text should probably use the new canonical link, or at least it should not use the MCVE name if you want to expunge the memory of MCVE.

---

<sup>For those with short memories, or who weren't paying attention in May 2019:

• *[A less awkward name for MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/)*

• *[MCVExit Redux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/)*</sup>

---

<sup>[Ralph Waldo Emerson](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored):</sup>

> A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do. He may as well concern himself with his shadow on the wall. Speak what you think now in hard words, and to-morrow speak what to-morrow thinks in hard words again, though it contradict every thing you said to-day.

Comment: /help/mcve still works along with a few others, they redirect to /help/minimal-reproducible-example. I don't really understand what the fuss is about, especially in your comment on the question in question which seems superfluous at best given the fact that two people prior to you asked for MRE's.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I agree that the link works — but it uses the old name where it would be more sensible to ensure that it uses the `help/mre` or `help/minimal-repoducible-example` link instead, losing a vestige of MCVE.

Comment: @DavyM: No; I don't expect an edit to history.  I'm just suggesting that the future should use the new preferred nomenclature, not continue the old nomenclature (unless SO goes back to MCVE wholesale, which I'd prefer; in that case, there's nothing to do to this bit).

Comment: I see now, this is only in the typo reason, for example, [Same connection file works for 1 script but not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56462953/7795130). The debugging reason *does* use the updated link: [how to display the list commits in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56485270/7795130). Yeah, I'd say let's go for the consistency then.

Comment: I'm not sure this would actually be particularly beneficial. I'm not against it happening, but I wouldn't support someone spending time making the changes.

Comment: We have _always_ been allies with Minreprexonia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch; I've revised the off-topic reason to use a link to /help/minimal-reproducible-example. This will retroactively change it in all previously-closed questions which used that reason as well.

Past iterations of that that off-topic reason won't be affected, so you may still see it here and there on questions that were closed a very long time ago. (not impossible to do those too, but I'm lazy and it seems kinda weird to revise a *de-activated* close reason for such a minor thing)

Comment: As I commented under the question, I'm not worried about changing the history — MCVE was important for 5 years.  But going forward, SO should use the modern name in the link.  Thanks.