# Did MCVE change to MRE and why?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

So I could have sworn that the "Minimum Complete and Verifiable example" page existed and now when I search for it I find the "Minimal, Reproducible Example".

Did this get changed at some point to MRE?

If so for what reason?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark

Comment: [It's not as bad as it could have been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve).

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the links guys. I didnt find those post with my search. I just kept getting redirected to the new MRE link. I will read up on this change on those links.

Comment: Perhaps you will want to [upgrade your meta search technique](https://www.google.com/search?q=mcve+vs+mre+site:meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: They should change it to [Steve1989MREInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylpJP.jpg) and be done with it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ironically, that search (which is basically what I used to arrive here) now shows *this* question as the top result.  The actual post with the answer is result #15 or so in the search results.  While Shog9's post is very information, the title of this one is much more helpful and ... well, "searchable" :-).