# Please make /help/mre symlink to /help/mcve

Tags: bug, status-deferred, hyperlinks, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example

If MRE is now (ever since [the "reprex" brouhaha)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve) the [official term for what used to be called MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386134/did-mcve-change-to-mre-and-why), could we please also link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mre to the [pertinent help page?](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

The shorthand `[mre]` works fine in comments, but if you want to link from outside the site (such as, well, from a meta post), you still need to remember the old term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for lack of an MRE.

Comment: /help/mcve is itself a link to /help/minimal-reproducible-example for whatever that's worth.

Comment: I'm calling this a bug as it seems like an oversight given the current redirects and magic links in place.

Comment: FWIW, the redirects mostly exist to avoid breaking links (and since /help/mre never worked there were no links to break).