# Closing SO employee posts on Meta

Tags: discussion, scope, meta

There was recently a meta question posted [concerning Hot Meta Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387546/5827005).

Upon reading this question, I voted to close it as "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community," because it doesn't seem to seek input in my opinion.

After voting, I was reading through the comments, and saw that a moderator had posted a comment:

> Mod Note: Do not close this question, it's an employee's post and it's
>   here to stay. If you have an objection, vote or write an answer, don't
>   close it.

Does this mean that the community should not vote to close content based on who the user is who posted it (as in employee vs non-employee)? If so, why do we even have the ability to vote to close such questions? If not, will review (and subsequent closing of said questions) be for nothing, and be reversed?

Comment: It's a company **announcement**. No, they should not be closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it is purely an announcement, surely it should be on the blog and not on meta, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It seems to me that "company announcements" do not seek input or discussion, which is what Meta is for.

Comment: From the [What is Meta help entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): *Meta is for ... Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community*.

Comment: OP, the short, pragmatic answer to your question: SE are the admins here, they can do _whatever they want_. Tim can singlehandedly reopen his post as often as he wants, so close voting is at most a futile way of protest.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that close reason is for people posting rants, not employees (or moderators) posting announcements. The former doesn't want a response, the latter does.

Comment: @ChrisF But why does the latter "want response"? It seems any community response is just ignored a majority of the time anyways. Thanks for posting your comment, I'm really seeking discussion here.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - OK. "want" is probably the wrong word. With announcements you're open to feedback, with a rant you're not. That's what I was driving at.

Comment: @l4mpi I wasn't really trying to _protest_ per say, whether I agree or disagree with the post in general doesn't change the fact that I believe it's not seeking input or discussion. But I see your point

Comment: Regardless of who posted it or whether it was an announcement, the OP finished the question with "questions? please leave an answer". That is as direct a request for community input as is possible and thus such a close reason is completely invalid. Whether OP will listen/care about the answers posted is a separate matter.

Comment: Closing such a question does the *exact* opposit of what you're trying to accomplish though... The only thing closing it will serve for is to *prevent* users from joining the debate, and making their frustration known. Next step for them would be to take away the option to vote close their posts when it really matters (which imo don't think will happen on meta, as its purpose is to support quite a broad range of topics), as it turns out to be used incorrectly. Well done, you've just played yourself.

Comment: @remy_rm Well, my point was really that there wasn't really a _debate_ at all, as input is ignored regardless. We close other questions for this reason, so I don't think your argument really holds up. My goal was not to allow or disallow people to comment or post to this question, it was to get an answer to the question "does it matter if a question which is normally off-topic when posted by a user should be closed if it were posted by an employee", which I got an answer to, I was genuinely interested in the discussion about this, I now understand why the answer is "No", which was my goal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Meta is *not just for discussions, bug reports and feature requests*. It is also a vehicle for company announcements to the community. The post is simply *not off topic*. It is a company announcement, and should not be closed.

From the [*What is Meta* documentantion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Meta is for...
>
> - [...]
> - ...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community

Remember that Stack Overflow is a site that was created and hosted by a company, with employees, and from time to time there are important things to communicate. Meta is an excellent place for that, as it can be directed to the people *actually using the platform*. That's different from the blog, which has a much, much wider audience.

This is even more true for announcements *about how Meta works*. Those definitely do not belong on the blog. Why inflict that on the wider world?

This is apart from the fact that interaction with a post on Meta is completely different from interacting with a blog post. Here we have accounts, community moderation tools, voting, answers, etc, a far richer toolset than comments on a blog, where only company employees can moderate the comments.

Comment: So what is the blog for, specifically to have multiple avenues of the company making announcements? Community consensus doesn't matter for these posts, so why not just post them on the blog?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: because the blog is not the right communication medium for that. The blog addresses the wider world, *not just the people using the site*.

Answer (score 9):

When employees use meta, they usually have specific purposes outside of what is usual here. As they usually speak for the company, a post by an employee often works as a sort of hybrid announcement / mild solicitation for opinion and feedback.

It is their platform, and topicality rules are more lax on meta anyways.

Even if you disagree with this, they have moderator status, any closure we perform will only serve to annoy a mod or CM who has to undo it.

Comment: The recent post was most certainly not a "solicitation for opinion or feedback".

Answer (score 5):

Notionally meta is for two way communication between Stack Overflow the company and the community; but as we're all experiencing: If that's the purpose of Meta, it's not fulfilling that purpose well.  Stack Overflow community members are frustrated by a lack of being heard and a lack of their desires being fulfilled, and I can imagine there are people in Stack Overflow the company who are similarly frustrated with some members of the community for being obstinate about change. (I do not speak for the company; I am putting myself in their shoes).

Realistically, we should probably have a better suited place for that; or better written boundaries as to what we as a community can expect from the company on Meta.

Right now our expectations (that we are heard, understood, listened to, and followed) do not match reality (we are heard, perhaps understood, maybe listened to, but not generally followed).

This question (and others like it) being closed is perhaps the community exercising what little agency it has with these frustrations.  We will not close employee posts (if we close them then the community cannot respond!), but we do understand the frustrations present in these actions.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I've come to a much better understanding on _why_ these types of questions are posted to Meta, even if the community has very little say in the actual direction of what is being discussed (as opposed to a blog post). Like others, I've felt very burnt lately by a lack of real communication, a lack of community involvement, etc. But I know this isn't the fault of any certain individual, everyone is just doing their best. The only thing I can do is post questions like this when I don't understand why things are a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

First, some comments on the general question that you raise. Another obvious example of this was the [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) post from awhile back. That received numerous close votes from people who argued that it was basically an extended rant (which it kind of was). It now has a historical-lock on it by a staff member, which has the following text:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site** so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

Given that this is an implicit admission from the staff that the question *was*, in fact, off-topic, this kind of makes you wonder why it was reopened every time that the community tried to close it. At a minimum, this really looks like "sure, it's off-topic, but we really want to do that anyway."

Now, as for the post that they actually ask about. By definition, Meta is for topics that the staff actually wants feedback on. If they want to make an announcement but aren't interested in getting feedback on it (and it really appears that, in this case, they aren't), they should post it on their blog instead. If they don't want feedback and/or don't intend to act on the feedback, just make a blog post instead.

The post that this is about is currently the second-least-popular Meta post that's still available on the site (albeit by only a small margin - it could easily surpass that one as the most-unpopular proposal still shown on the site in the very near future).

In the case of the most-unpopular post, [at least SE backed down and modified the proposal in response to community feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark) and came up with a solution that everyone was happy about. I see no evidence of a similar willingness to compromise in this case. The fact that they [evidently implemented the change almost immediately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator#comment714473_387546) without even waiting to see what the community reaction was, along with how unresponsive staff has been to criticism of the post, kind of tells you how much feedback they want on this.

That being said, the close reason ("does not appear to seek input or discussion from the community") is perfectly accurate in this case - they *don't* want input. Independently of whether you think that they *should* solicit community input on this (and [I think that they should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator/387561#387561)), from a purely process perspective if they don't really want feedback they should put this on their blog instead. Even staff posts have to be on-topic; there's no reason that they should get special exemptions.

Also, if they really don't plan to incorporate our feedback, they should just be honest about that fact. The way that they did this looks cynical, dishonest, and high-handed.

**TL;DR** Meta's just for stuff that they want feedback on, and they clearly don't want feedback on this, so it's off-topic.

Comment: I agree with you, because this was my exact reasoning. However, it seems we are in the minority on this opinion. I realize now, my (our) opinion on this matter does not really matter (honestly, what's new?), because "staff can do whatever they want". Martijn said that blog posts aren't a good medium for announcements like this, due to the scope of the blog. However, it still _feels_ wrong to me to not enforce community standards for any post on Meta based solely on _who_ posted it. Seems like they should have some other medium which is obviously distinct from the normal Q&A format.

Comment: Obviously I can't compare this post in my example with a post from any non-staff, because they wouldn't make an announcement like this; but I can't help but feel like if something similar was posted by a user, with no mention of seeking input/discussion from anyone until the very end "Question? Post an answer", it would get closed

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I agree entirely - I was actually about to post the same question until I saw that you had. It seems wrong for them to get a free pass to violate quality standards just because they're staff; if you take out the "who they are" aspect of this, it would have been closed much faster, and almost certainly would have remained closed. You certainly wouldn't see moderators repeatedly overriding the community's close votes like you're seeing here; as of right now, 3 separate moderators have overridden the community 5 times on this post.