# Change "mwe" explanation from "minimal workable example" to "minimal working example"?

Tags: discussion, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example, terminology

I was reading the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page and I noticed that for some reason the `mwe` acronym is spelled out as **"minimal workable example"**.

However, I believe that **"minimal working example"** is far more common (e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) or [The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Minimal+Working+Example)).

Searching on Google for `"minimal workable example"` gives [~30](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNR7uSkFhtGPF8XiVdPmSZujioPsCA%3A1568745391615&ei=ryeBXbeUJYHCkwXuo7aQDA&q=%22minimal%20workable%20example%22&oq=%22minimal%20workable%20example%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39.23829.25053..25260...0.3..0.124.558.7j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i8i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i13j0i13i30j0i13i5i30.hpfzGdWfkrw&ved=0ahUKEwj3p73-v9jkAhUB4aQKHe6RDcIQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) hits versus the [~435'000](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSloeJ23dBDEfO2OCnCK2V6MgUrUA%3A1568744372660&ei=tCOBXYn4J9GUsAe2j7CwDw&q=%22minimal%20working%20example%22&oq=%22minimal%20working%20example%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l3.0.0..646435...0.9..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.JKHwSxqLhFw&ved=0ahUKEwiJos2YvNjkAhVRCuwKHbYHDPYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) hits of `"minimal working example"`.

Even searching on Stack Overflow Meta gives [~5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=minimal%20workable%20example) hits for `minimal workable example` and [~230](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=minimal%20working%20example) hits for `minimal working example`.

Therefore, I would suggest the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page to be modified accordingly.

---

**NOTE**: this question is *not* about what *official* name should be adopted on Stack Overflow for the concept of "minimal {working | reproducible | complete verifiable | verifiable complete} example" (which received [its fair share of attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331/5218354), perhaps with a somewhat questionable outcome). *It is about spelling out the acronym
**"mwe"** as **"minimal working example"**.*

Comment: Good catch, I'd say...

Comment: Why not "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"?  — Yes, sour grapes. — But why is it "mre" at all if the explanation is "minimal work{ing,able} example"; why isn't it "mwe"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If it was for me, I would have called the whole page `minimal working example` or `mwe` for short. I think this "mwe" acronym is what I've learned first. But regardless of what  *"official"* name is picked up for the page, one could always spell out "mwe" *correctly* in the text of the page. I am only trying to make this last change happen.

Comment: Also, might be confused with "meal ready to eat" in military parlance.

Comment: @NeilButterworth this has been brought up as a *positive*. Because somehow people who know what a military MRE would, upon seeing the acronym here, immediately figure out it's about code that is prepared and ready to run. I am honestly confused by this *specifically* because I was confused when I saw MRE and then reading the explanation. It didn't occur to me that MRE = sort of "code ready to be run".

Comment: I disagree with this. It will be misunderstood by a decent percentage of people. Why or how would anyone post a 'working' example of code that presumably doesn't work? 'Workable' implies that there may be an issue with the code, but it's in a state which you can work on it.

Comment: @PaulG Will it? I do not find a reference of your perceived meaning in the Merriem-Webster dictionary for [workable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workable) vs [working](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/working). On the other hand "working" as "adequate to permit work to be done" and "assumed or adopted to permit or facilitate further work or activity" perfectly fit the concept being conveyed with *"minimal {working | reproducible | complete verifiable | verfiable complete} example"* from the perspective of whoever is going to tackle the issue presented in the question.

Comment: I think you're stretching that definition quite hard there! The example you posted for working is in the context of 'a working majority'. Just my opinion, but if someone is looking for help with a bug and you tell them you'll only look at the issue if they can post a 'working example' it's going to cause a lot of confusion.