# Add magic comment for [mwe]

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Can you please add `[mwe]` as a magic link for comments that links to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Currently only `[mcve]`, `[mre]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]` and `[example]` are supported.

<sup>(I don't want engage in a discussion whether or not this is a good name, but it is a widely used term on other sites (for example tex.se) and I think it would be a nice thing to have for those people who are used to this name)</sup>

Comment: So, you're requesting another alias?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, that's the idea

Comment: What does the W in MWE stand for? I've never heard of this acronym (or seen it used).

Comment: @TylerH https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example defines it in the first paragraph as "minimal workable example". Personally I prefer "minimal working example"

Comment: @TylerH The most accepted meaning for the `w` in "mwe" is "working". See also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389465/5218354), where I give some numbers for this.

Comment: Well, if you pronounce it like Elmer Fudd, it W would be wepwoducible, right? :-)