# How to cite an answer in APA format

Tags: support, answers

I'm writing a paper, and some of the answers of the questions I have asked have been helpful. How should I properly cite the answers?

The APA format is required.

Comment: What citation format is required for your manuscript? Generally, you would include the author's name, the posting date, a link to the answer (which you can obtain by clicking the "share" link), and (optionally) the title of the question to which the answer was posted. All content posted here is [licensed under CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: @CodyGray I had a similar case [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091912/parsing-filtering-json-data-from-api-into-c-sharp-application/62093566#comment109845297_62093566). Obviously a last name is required in citation formats  ....

Comment: @rene [Stack Exchange to the rescue!](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66033/how-to-cite-in-apa-format-for-an-author-who-uses-only-a-first-name) You are a mononym. Which is weird, considering flowers are paraphyletic. :-)

Comment: @rene Why don't you just tell your full name?

Comment: @oguzismail because my full name doesn't matter, at least not here.

Comment: Why didn't Plato just tell us his full name, @oguzismail?

Comment: @Cody No idea, because he was too arrogant? Or his full name was known, but forgotten over centuries as no other philosopher named Plato appeared?

Comment: Ancient Greeks had only a single name; there were no surnames or family names. Sometimes, you saw it written with a patronymic reference (e.g., "Demosthenes, son of Demosthenes of Paiania"). You also sometimes see a reference to the person's place of origin (e.g., "Pythagoras of Samos"), if relevant, but that's still not a last name. It certainly isn't arrogance. See also: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: The same way you would cite an online source - this is something that you should direct to your supervisor or lecturer. Trust me, I mark such papers using APA referencing. It's what I do for a living.

Comment: @Cody Okay, but I don't see how it's still relevant in 21st century. There must be thousands of people named *Oğuz* now, do I really have the right to claim ownership of the name, and make people refer to me by only *Oğuz* in citations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Purdue University College of Liberal Arts Online Writing Lab (OWL)](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/reference_list_electronic_sources.html), the format is:

```
Lastname, F. M. (Year, Month Date). Title of page. Site name. URL
```

If we apply that to an answer on Meta Stack Overflow, it should look like:

> Ok, that was... not a great idea
>
> – Shog9. (2019, May 22). *MCVExit redux: I don't need a milkshake to know when I've missed the mark*. Meta Stack Overflow. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331/](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331)

Note that, although the citation requires "Lastname, F. M.", all of those pieces might not be available on Stack Overflow, where some users choose to use [pseudoynyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym). In this case, you should use the name the user chooses to go by here (e.g., "Shog9", "Machavity", etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure what the convention is, but for answers on a Q&A site, I would do "Answer to: <Question Title>" for the "Title of page" field. Otherwise, it might look like you were citing the question itself (user name notwithstanding).

Comment: This question should be directed to the user's supervisor or lecturer.  I don't really care that it's here, but it's not something that should be relied upon, as the University should provide the guidelines

Comment: It should also be double spaced with a hanging indent, within the reference list, with an inline citation used.

Comment: This looks like we are citing the question itself, as @CodyGray says. Here's another question I have: how to cite multiple answers ?

Comment: @AbelLIFAEFIMBULA Answers have their own URL structure for easy citation. There's a "Share" link below each one that will give you said URL. I would structure your citations as my example for questions does