# Minimum working example in Django

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

The intention of this question is to better understand how to properly ask questions on SO.

I have been reading SO for quite some time, and have not been posting that much as I was afraid of being downvoted again if I missed something. Now I would like to post a new question about a Django issue, but I'm not sure how to provide a minimal working example in Django. Should it be a published website with running Django on the webserver or should it be an archive with the respective Django files?

Also, I've noticed that many questions, which were not downvoted, didn't have minimal working examples. Why were those questions met without issue? By asking this, I would like to understand when it is proper to not include a working minimal example.

Comment: It's needed for debugging questions so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: "Also, I've noticed that many questions, which were not down-voted, didn't have minimal working examples" - not all questions need one, but these have an extremely specific scope (and, to second Jeanne, aren't debugging questions). Most new questions asked that may fit that description are duplicates or otherwise off-topic, because people. There are, of course, one-off questions that are absolute garbage and still doesn't get downvoted and close, but that's an unfortunate side-effect of not having nearly enough curators.

Comment: I have seen many questions on SO that ask about errors (they fall into the debugging category), but do not give a minimum working example, and do not have any issues, and are up-voted. In fact, I see this sort of questions almost every day. To the contrary, it is quite rare that I see a debugging question that gives a minimal working example. At least when it comes to Python or Django.

Comment: If most of the readers are able to reproduce the same ***issue*** as you have ***with the given details***, you may not need to add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But, this way you are probably assuming that the readers have a very good knowledge at guessing your issue. Some of the people may not need a mre ***always*** to answer the question, because they may have a good experience at the particular language/framework/tag. I would usually add a mre so that the issue can even be reproduced by a noob which may result in a good answer.

Comment: It depends. If your question deals with making queries / creating or updating a model / forms for a model relevant parts of the model are a must. If you have an error do share the error message (and not that interactive message that you get on the debug page, use the "Switch to copy-paste view" button on that page). Next if your question is about some form not working share: relevant url patterns, view, form class, template. There are more things to consider and you should treat each question individually. (You don't need a published website or an archive of the code, but you can share them)

Comment: For any web stack, it should be possible to isolate a problem to a single layer: front end (javascript), view layer (form processing, template generation) or the model layer (reading writing from the database).  If this can be done, the example can be the relevant code with a problem description and traceback.  If the problem cannot be isolated then an example that works on the dev-server out of the box is necessary.  This should consist of the minimum code to reproduce.   For view layer issues you can sometimes avoid including html by providing `curl`  command to simulate browser activity.

Comment: The question is not only what to include but also what to leave out. Remove as much as possible from the project until the problem doesn't occur anymore, than go back one step.

Comment: I second @Trilarion. Forcing askers to post an MRE is the best way for them to get an answer, **because 90% of the time paring down your problem to an MRE will show you the issue**, so you've answered your own question. It's not an arbitrary requirement, it's not just to help other users - it's first and foremost to help **you**, the asker.

Comment: Heads up that many "X questions" don't actually depend on that X – in Python I've seen a fair share of questions styled as issues about concurrency backends, data analysis packages, but also web frameworks, when they did not depend on these things *at all*. Before preparing an MRE for a "Django issue", make sure Django is actually relevant.

Comment: Man, I completely get you even if you get good examples, it can happen to you just look at my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390589/how-to-auto-adjust-the-height-of-a-webview-in-xamarin-android-or-android-based

This question hasn't been solved in over a decade. You can find similar questions with poorer answers and examples than mine. In my case, I provided a fully functional code and a fully functional answer and both were downvoted without any comment. I am also very careful when I ask any question in SO.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As a gold badge holder of the [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) tag.

A minimum working example in most cases just means the view and models, possibly any URLs and templates involved so that we can work out what the workflow is with your issue. If the issue is with middleware or context processors then those too.

If you've got large class-based views or large models with multiple functions then we really don't care about them (irrelevant functions), just the details needed that would be involved in getting a clear picture of the issue.

Most of the people that answer Django questions regularly are very adept at understanding where issues lie without actually needing to run your Django application. This I'm sure doesn't apply to every issue but the vast majority. For the latter, what tends to happen is I'll recreate an issue in my own code base/sandbox using my own models in a similar fashion to what your question portrays so for these a minimum example needs to demonstrate clearly the bare minimum I need to be able to do this.

Comment: So "runnable" in MRE means that a person with sufficient skills in the topic can easily complete the presented code to make it runnable.

Comment: @Trilarion - "reproducable"  means I should have enough code to reproduce the issue, even if that just means I'm able to manifest that in my head

Comment: Sure, that's the idea, although it's a bit subjective especially for frameworks where you can never add everything. You may be able to do more in your head than I in mine. :)

Comment: @Trilarion - You just always have to visualise that you're creating a unit test where the assertion is going to fail and you'll be fine :)

Answer (score 4):

The term is not "minimum work*ing* example", it's "minimum work**able** example". "Working" and "workable" are two very different words and the latter is chosen with care:

> workable, adj.: **capable of producing the desired effect or result**; practicable; feasible.

Thus, the term "minimum workable example" means:

- the *smallest amount of code*
- that, if pasted into a new project in the language and/or framework in question, will **(re)produce** the issue you're encountering
- and thus provides an *example* of your problem that prospective answerers can view or run on their own computers

---

Considering how many non-native-English speakers Stack Overflow gets nowadays, coupled with the many people who read "working" instead of "workable" (not pointing fingers at you OP, I am quite certain this happens a lot), I would suggest purging the potentially-confusing "minimal workable example" language from the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In fact, I'd be in favour of getting rid of every term except "minimal reproducible example" (yes, that includes nuking MCVE) - I've never seen the need to have more than one term for one thing, especially when the synonyms are either more wordy or more open to being misconstrued.

Comment: So.. there's still a chance for a good comeback of [Min-Reprex: a less awkward name for MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384994/min-reprex-a-less-awkward-name-for-mcve) ;)

Comment: I gather the actual term is "minimal reproducible example", not "working" or "workable".

Comment: @Scratte [I have consulted the computer, and it has a message for you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOdjCb4LwQY)

Comment: @sequence In my mind, that's the simplest and least ambiguous of the various terms, yes. But I'm interested to know whether **you** find it better than "minimum workable example" and/or "minimal, complete and verifiable example"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the right way to look at this is: how much work are you willing to do to make it easier for volunteers to answer your question?

I'm answering from a C perspective, not Django, but I can say that that when it comes to "debugging" questions, a properly-posted, runnable example can be *hugely* useful to answerers.  Sometimes, a prose problem description, or an isolated code fragment, makes a problem obvious, but sometimes, the problem appears just as opaque to an expert as it is to the person asking it.  But one of the things that makes me good at debugging is that I have a debugger and I know how to use it.  Sometimes it takes seconds — literally just a few seconds! — to copy-and-paste someone's code sample onto my machine, compile it, reproduce the error, fire up the debugger, and spot the problem.

And this is why the "regulars" are always harping on OP's to post complete, runnable code.  (Evidently this is an impossibly hard request for many OP's to fulfill, however, given how often they post either (a) images of their code, or (b) code which they have tediously retyped into their browser, rather than copy-and-pasting it, meaning that what we see on SO is *not* quite the code they're asking about.)

Again, my comments here apply to traditional, compiled languages like C, not necessarily to web frameworks like Django.